# Merge rows in a dataframe where the rows are disjoint and contain NAs

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, coalesce

I have a dataframe that has two rows:

```
| code | name  | v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 |
|------|-------|----|----|----|----|
| 345  | Yemen | NA | 2  | 3  | NA |
| 346  | Yemen | 4  | NA | NA | 5  |
```

Is there an easy way to merge these two rows?
What if I rename "345" in "346", would that make things easier?

Comment: You will need some rule for combining non-NA column. Such as will you always take the first occcurence or last, the mean of numeric columns etc.

Comment: The coalesce() functionality is needed here . Found a good discussion on this thread : [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r[link]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use [`aggregate`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/aggregate.html). Assuming that you want to merge rows with identical values in column `name`:

```
aggregate(x=DF[c("v1","v2","v3","v4")], by=list(name=DF$name), min, na.rm = TRUE)
   name v1 v2 v3 v4
1 Yemen  4  2  3  5
```

This is like the SQL `SELECT name, min(v1) GROUP BY name`. The `min` function is arbitrary, you could also use `max` or `mean`, all of them return the non-NA value from an NA and a non-NA value if `na.rm = TRUE`.
(An SQL-like `coalesce()` function would sound better if existed in R.)

However, you should check first if all non-NA values for a given `name` is identical. For example, run the `aggregate` both with `min` and `max` and compare, or run it with `range`.

Finally, if you have many more variables than just v1-4, you could use `DF[,!(names(DF) %in% c("code","name"))]` to define the columns.

Comment: running your example gives me `Error in DF$name : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`

Comment: @MattO'Brien how does your DF look like? Is it a data frame? Does if have multiple columns? Do you have code to replicate the error?

Answer (score 4):

Adding `dplyr` & `data.table` solutions for completeness

**Using `dplyr::coalesce()`**

```r
library(dplyr)

sum_NA <- function(x) {if (all(is.na(x))) x[NA_integer_] else sum(x, na.rm = TRUE)}

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise_all(sum_NA)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>   name   code    v1    v2    v3    v4
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Yemen   691     4     2     3     5

# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45515491
# Supply lists by splicing them into dots:
coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
  return(dplyr::coalesce(!!! as.list(df)))
}

df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise_all(coalesce_by_column)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#>   name   code    v1    v2    v3    v4
#>   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 Yemen   345     4     2     3     5
```

**Using `data.table`**

```r
# Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28036294/
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = name]
#>     name code v1 v2 v3 v4
#> 1: Yemen  345  4  2  3  5
#> 2: Yemen  346  4  2  3  5

setDT(df)[, code := NULL][, lapply(.SD, na.omit), by = name]    
#>     name v1 v2 v3 v4
#> 1: Yemen  4  2  3  5

setDT(df)[, code := NULL][, lapply(.SD, sum_NA), by = name]
#>     name v1 v2 v3 v4
#> 1: Yemen  4  2  3  5
```