# How to implement coalesce efficiently in R

Tags: r, coalesce

### Background

Several SQL languages (I mostly use postgreSQL) have a function called coalesce which returns the first non null column element for each row. This can be very efficient to use when tables have a lot of `NULL` elements in them.

I encounter this in a lot of scenarios in R as well when dealing with not so structured data which has a lot of NA's in them.

I have made a naive implementation myself but it is ridiculously slow.

```
coalesce <- function(...) {
  apply(cbind(...), 1, function(x) {
          x[which(!is.na(x))[1]]
        })
}
```

### Example

```
a <- c(1,  2,  NA, 4, NA)
b <- c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 6)
c <- c(7,  8,  NA, 9, 10)
coalesce(a,b,c)
# [1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

### Question

Is there any efficient way to implement `coalesce` in R?

Comment: How do you define "ridiculously slow"? (The call you describe takes ~100 microseconds on my machine). How many vectors do you have, and how long are they? (Incidentally, one way that speeds it up *slightly* (~5%) is to do `x[!is.na(x)][1]` instead of `x[which(!is.na(x))[1]]`)

Comment: The main difficulty here IMO is vectorization doesn't help much in solving this problem; a lot of elements are needlessly probed by `which` and `is.na`, and `cbind` + `apply` will make copies of the data and will be slow for large vectors. I would recommend an `Rcpp` solution (and may try to cook something up later).

Comment: Yeah, I have quite large vectors. The problem I'm working on atm uses vectors of length `608247`. Which is a bit longer than the example.

Comment: coalesce() also fails if all parameters are NULL. This is a quick fix:
`"%??%" <- coalesce <- function(..., default = NA) apply(cbind(..., default), 1, function(x) x[which(!is.na(x))[1]])`

Comment: See answers to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37714533/merge-join-prioritizing-non-missing-values) for suggestions for incorporating coalesce functions into merges/joins.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

On my machine, using `Reduce` gets a 5x performance improvement:

```
coalesce2 <- function(...) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) {
    i <- which(is.na(x))
    x[i] <- y[i]
    x},
  list(...))
}

> microbenchmark(coalesce(a,b,c),coalesce2(a,b,c))
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min       lq   median       uq     max neval
  coalesce(a, b, c) 97.669 100.7950 102.0120 103.0505 243.438   100
 coalesce2(a, b, c) 19.601  21.4055  22.8835  23.8315  45.419   100
```

Comment: Thanks! This is tremendously faster! Second time today Reduce saves my ass. Tried to do something like this myself but I couldn't figure it out. Awesome.

Comment: Works great if vectors passed are the same length. I had problems with this because I was trying coalesce2(NULL, c(3, 2)), so is.na() gave me warnings whereas coalesce() just repeats NA twice for the first column.

Comment: This fails if either is `NULL` instead of just `NA`. Recommend use of `is.null`.

Answer (score 25):

From `data.table >= 1.12.3` you can use `fcoalesce`.

```
library(data.table)
fcoalesce(a, b, c)
# [1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

---

`fcoalesce` can also take "a single plain list, data.table or data.frame". Thus, if the vectors above were columns in a `data.frame` (or a `data.table`), we could simply supply the name of the data set:

```
d = data.frame(a, b, c)
# or d = data.table(a, b, c) 
fcoalesce(d)
# [1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

---

For more info, including a benchmark, see [NEWS item #18 for development version 1.12.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md#changes-in-v1123--in-development).

Answer (score 24):

Looks like coalesce1 is still available

```
coalesce1 <- function(...) {
    ans <- ..1
    for (elt in list(...)[-1]) {
        i <- is.na(ans)
        ans[i] <- elt[i]
    }
    ans
}
```

which is faster still (but more-or-less a hand re-write of `Reduce`, so less general)

```
> identical(coalesce(a, b, c), coalesce1(a, b, c))
[1] TRUE
> microbenchmark(coalesce(a,b,c), coalesce1(a, b, c), coalesce2(a,b,c))
Unit: microseconds
               expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
  coalesce(a, b, c) 336.266 341.6385 344.7320 355.4935 538.348   100
 coalesce1(a, b, c)   8.287   9.4110  10.9515  12.1295  20.940   100
 coalesce2(a, b, c)  37.711  40.1615  42.0885  45.1705  67.258   100
```

Or for larger data compare

```
coalesce1a <- function(...) {
    ans <- ..1
    for (elt in list(...)[-1]) {
        i <- which(is.na(ans))
        ans[i] <- elt[i]
    }
    ans
}
```

showing that `which()` can sometimes be effective, even though it implies a second pass through the index.

```
> aa <- sample(a, 100000, TRUE)
> bb <- sample(b, 100000, TRUE)
> cc <- sample(c, 100000, TRUE)
> microbenchmark(coalesce1(aa, bb, cc),
+                coalesce1a(aa, bb, cc),
+                coalesce2(aa,bb,cc), times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
  coalesce1(aa, bb, cc) 11.110024 11.137963 11.145723 11.212907 11.270533    10
 coalesce1a(aa, bb, cc)  2.906067  2.953266  2.962729  2.971761  3.452251    10
  coalesce2(aa, bb, cc)  3.080842  3.115607  3.139484  3.166642  3.198977    10
```

Comment: Interesting that it's so much faster than Reduce.  My guess would be that it's because the loop version avoids the overhead of a function call (or possibly some parameter checking), which might be a bottleneck when the inputs are small.  That would explain why the times are much closer with large inputs.

Comment: @MartinMorgan +1! maybe you should add a test on number of arguments something like ` if(length(list(...)>0)){}` to avoid an error when you call `coalesce1()` without arguments..

Answer (score 21):

Using *dplyr* package:

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(a, b, c)
# [1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

Benchamark, not as fast as accepted solution:

```
coalesce2 <- function(...) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) {
    i <- which(is.na(x))
    x[i] <- y[i]
    x},
    list(...))
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  coalesce(a, b, c),
  coalesce2(a, b, c)
)

# Unit: microseconds
#                expr    min     lq     mean median      uq     max neval cld
#   coalesce(a, b, c) 21.951 24.518 27.28264 25.515 26.9405 126.293   100   b
#  coalesce2(a, b, c)  7.127  8.553  9.68731  9.123  9.6930  27.368   100  a
```

But on a larger dataset, it is comparable:

```
aa <- sample(a, 100000, TRUE)
bb <- sample(b, 100000, TRUE)
cc <- sample(c, 100000, TRUE)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  coalesce(aa, bb, cc),
  coalesce2(aa, bb, cc))

# Unit: milliseconds
#                   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#   coalesce(aa, bb, cc) 1.708511 1.837368 5.468123 3.268492 3.511241 96.99766   100   a
#  coalesce2(aa, bb, cc) 1.474171 1.516506 3.312153 1.957104 3.253240 91.05223   100   a
```

Answer (score 9):

I have a ready-to-use implementation called `coalesce.na` in [my misc package](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc). It seems to be competitive, but not fastest.
It will also work for vectors of different length, and has a special treatment for vectors of length one:

```
                    expr        min          lq      median          uq         max neval
    coalesce(aa, bb, cc) 990.060402 1030.708466 1067.000698 1083.301986 1280.734389    10
   coalesce1(aa, bb, cc)  11.356584   11.448455   11.804239   12.507659   14.922052    10
  coalesce1a(aa, bb, cc)   2.739395    2.786594    2.852942    3.312728    5.529927    10
   coalesce2(aa, bb, cc)   2.929364    3.041345    3.593424    3.868032    7.838552    10
 coalesce.na(aa, bb, cc)   4.640552    4.691107    4.858385    4.973895    5.676463    10
```

Here's the code:

```
coalesce.na <- function(x, ...) {
  x.len <- length(x)
  ly <- list(...)
  for (y in ly) {
    y.len <- length(y)
    if (y.len == 1) {
      x[is.na(x)] <- y
    } else {
      if (x.len %% y.len != 0)
        warning('object length is not a multiple of first object length')
      pos <- which(is.na(x))
      x[pos] <- y[(pos - 1) %% y.len + 1]
    }
  }
  x
}
```

Of course, as Kevin pointed out, an Rcpp solution might be faster by orders of magnitude.

Answer (score 5):

A *very* simple solution is to use the `ifelse` function from the `base` package:

```
coalesce3 <- function(x, y) {

    ifelse(is.na(x), y, x)
}
```

Although it appears to be slower than `coalesce2` above:

```
test <- function(a, b, func) {

    for (i in 1:10000) {

        func(a, b)
    }
}

system.time(test(a, b, coalesce2))
user  system elapsed 
0.11    0.00    0.10 

system.time(test(a, b, coalesce3))
user  system elapsed 
0.16    0.00    0.15
```

---

You can use `Reduce` to make it work for an arbitrary number of vectors:

```
coalesce4 <- function(...) {

    Reduce(coalesce3, list(...))
}
```

Comment: Sure. But this does not work for more than two vectors. What if you have an arbitrary amount of vectors?

Comment: Yes that is a limitation. Quick fix is to use `Reduce`.

Comment: interestingly, an explicit if-else does not convert dates to numbers, but `ifelse()` does. So you function on dates does not work: `coalesce4(NULL, lubridate::ymd('2019-05-01'))` returns `18017`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

`coalesce <- function(x){
  y <- head( x[is.na(x) == F] , 1)
  return(y)
}`

It returns first vaule which is not NA and it works on `data.table`, for example if you want to use coalesce on few columns and these column names are in vector of strings:

`column_names <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")`

how to use:

`ranking[, coalesce_column := coalesce( mget(column_names) ), by = 1:nrow(ranking)]`

Comment: Turning into a one-row-at-a-time operation is pretty inefficient, and the syntax seems weird to me.

Answer (score 2):

An elegant solution in BASE is to define:

`coalesce <- function(...) na.omit(c(...))[1]`

So for vectors:

```
a <- c(1,  2,  NA, 4, NA)
b <- c(NA, NA, NA, 5, 6)
c <- c(7,  8,  NA, 9, 10)
```

The output is the desired:

```
> mapply(coalesce, a, b,c)
[1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

On my machine this beats the accepted answer using `Reduce`.

```
> microbenchmark(coalesce(a,b,c),coalesce2(a,b,c))
Unit: microseconds
               expr min  lq   mean median  uq    max neval
  coalesce(a, b, c) 5.6 5.7  6.527    5.9 6.1   43.6   100
 coalesce2(a, b, c) 7.6 7.9 39.191    8.0 8.4 3040.1   100
```

Comment: Nice to see a new approach to an old question! I was curious and ran a benchmark using the "large" `aa; bb; cc` data in Martin Morgan's answer. On the large data, this approach is not competitive, about 300x slower than the `coalesce1a` and `coalesce2` options.

Comment: @GregorThomas to me it's a different question if $N$ is huge. Each time `c` is called, R has to check the type conformance which is a waste. It's better if `aa`, `bb`, and `cc` are already in a data.frame, `X`. In that case, acceptable solutions are more like `apply(X, 1, function(x) na.omit(x)[1])`.

Comment: I think performance hardly matters if N is small. Who cares about saving 33 microseconds? If we put the big data in `df = data.frame(aa, bb, cc)` then `coalesce2(df$aa, df$bb, df$cc)` is closer to 400x faster than `apply(df, 1, function(x) na.omit(x)[1])`, probably a bigger margin due to `apply`'s implicit conversion to `matrix`.

Answer (score 1):

Another apply method, with `mapply`.

```
mycoalesce <- function(...) {
  temp <- c(...)
  temp[!is.na(temp)][1]
}
mapply(mycoalesce, a, b, c)
[1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

This selects the first non-NA value if more than one exists. The last non-missing element could be selected using `tail`.

Maybe a bit more speed could be squeezed out of this alternative using the bare bones `.mapply` function, which looks a little different.

```
unlist(.mapply(function(...) {temp <- c(...); temp[!is.na(temp)][1]},
               dots=list(a, b, c), MoreArgs=NULL))
[1]  1  2 NA  4  6
```

`.mapply`differs in important ways from its non-dotted cousin.

- it returns a list (like `Map`) and so must be wrapped in some function like `unlist` or `c` to return a vector.
- the set of arguments to be fed in parallel to the function in FUN must be given in a list to the dots argument.
- Finally, `mapply`, the moreArgs argument does not have a default, so must explicitly be fed NULL.