# Coaelsce function in R

Tags: r

I have a data.frame with NA's and I would like to coalesce them relative to their location in the data.frame and finally if all in a row are missing then use some arbitray value I provide :

I've come up with this code which works recursively on the supplied `...` argument.
I'm pretty sure there is a better idea though, or a built in function.

```
coalesce <- function(x,...) {

  fillerList <- list(...)
    y <- try(y <- unlist(..1))
    if(class(y)=="try-error" | length(y)==0L) {
        x <- x 
    }
    else if(length(y)==1L) {
     x[is.na(x)] <- y
    }
    else {
     x[is.na(x)] <- y[is.na(x)]
    }
    # recursion
    if(length(fillerList)-1L<=0L) {return(x)}
    else {return(coalesce(x,fillerList[-1]))}
}
```

Comment: Reproducible example please.  An example of the output you want would also be helpful.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r) recent question?

Answer (score 1):

I have a ready-to-use implementation called `coalesce.na` in [my misc package](https://github.com/krlmlr/kimisc). Install using

```
library(devtools)
install_github("krlmlr/kimisc")
```

and use it just like in your implementation.

As seen in [my answer to the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20281888/946850), it is competitive to other solutions in terms of runtime and offers extra features such as allowing to use vectors of different length.