# What is the best way to combine the two mutually exclusive columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

```
> df <- data.frame(A=c("a",NA,"b"),B=c(NA,"c",NA))
> df
     A    B
1    a <NA>
2 <NA>    c
3    b <NA>
```

How do I get to:

```
> df
  A
1 a
2 c
3 b
```

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/324364) might be helpful.

Comment: ...also, please pay attention to your tags. The description for the tips-and-tricks tag says in big bold letters not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
 df <- with(df, data.frame(AB=ifelse(is.na(A), as.character(B), as.character(A))))
> df
  AB
1  a
2  c
3  b
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. Here's one way

```
data.frame(A=apply(df,1,na.omit))
```