# Coalesce two string columns with alternating missing values to one

Tags: r, na, missing-data

I have a data frame with two columns "a" and "b" with alternating missing values (`NA`)

```
a      b
dog    <NA>
mouse  <NA>
<NA>   cat
bird   <NA>
```

I want to "merge" / combine them to a new column c that looks like this, i.e. the non-`NA` element in each row is selected:

```
c
dog
mouse
cat
bird
```

I tried `merge` and `join`, but neither worked as I wanted. Maybe because I do not have an id with which to merge? For integers I would just circumvent this and add both columns, but how in my case?

Comment: Are those real `NA` values or fake?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You may try `pmax`

```
df$c <- pmax(df$a, df$b)
df
#       a    b     c
# 1   dog <NA>   dog
# 2 mouse <NA> mouse
# 3  <NA>  cat   cat
# 4  bird <NA>  bird
```

...or `ifelse`:

`df$c <- ifelse(is.na(df$a), df$b, df$a)`

For more general solutions in cases with more than two columns, you find several ways to implement coalesce in R [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r).

Comment: the best solution for me was the second option using `ifelse`. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

`dplyr` has exactly what you are looking for, function `coalesce()`

```
library(dplyr)

a<-c("dog","mouse",NA,"bird")
b<-c(NA,NA,"cat",NA)

coalesce(a,b)

[1] "dog"   "mouse" "cat"   "bird"
```

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a [coalesce()](https://gist.github.com/MrFlick/10205794) function for this type of task which works much like the SQL coalesce function. You would use it like

```
dd<-read.table(text="a      b
dog    NA
mouse  NA
NA   cat
bird   NA", header=T)

dd$c <- with(dd, coalesce(a,b))
dd
#       a    b     c
# 1   dog <NA>   dog
# 2 mouse <NA> mouse
# 3  <NA>  cat   cat
# 4  bird <NA>  bird
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's my attempt (modified by @MrFlick)

```
df$c <- apply(df, 1, function(x) na.omit(x)[1])
df
#       a    b     c
# 1   dog <NA>   dog
# 2 mouse <NA> mouse
# 3  <NA>  cat   cat
# 4  bird <NA>  bird
```

Comment: Wouldn't `apply(df, 1, function(x) na.omit(x)[1])` work just as well here, and be a bit simpler?

Comment: I would also use `df[which(!is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)]`

Comment: @akrun, that is very nice vectoerized approach. I would post it as your own answer

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `which` with `arr.ind=TRUE`

```
indx <- which(!is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
df$c <-  df[indx][order(indx[,1])]
df
#    a    b     c
#1   dog <NA>   dog
#2 mouse <NA> mouse
#3  <NA>  cat   cat
#4  bird <NA>  bird
```

Or

```
df$c <- df[cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(!is.na(df)))]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a simple `apply` :

```
df$c <- apply(df,1,function(x)  x[!is.na(x)]  ) 

> df
      a    b     c
1   dog <NA>   dog
2 mouse <NA> mouse
3  <NA>  cat   cat
4  bird <NA>  bird
```

Answer (score 2):

Using if else logic:

```
a<-c("dog","mouse",NA,"bird")
b<-c(NA,NA,"cat",NA)

test.df <-data.frame(a,b, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
test.df$c <- ifelse(is.na(test.df$a), test.df$b, test.df$a)

test.df

      a    b     c
1   dog <NA>   dog
2 mouse <NA> mouse
3  <NA>  cat   cat
4  bird <NA>  bird
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`tidyr::unite`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/unite.html) to be safe in case of a row containing two values:

```
df <- df |>
 unite(c,
       c(a, b),
       remove = FALSE,
       na.rm = TRUE)
```