# How to combine two columns of a data-frame with missing data?

Tags: r, missing-data

This is an extension of [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563531/combine-column-to-remove-nas). How can I combine two columns of a data frame as

```
data <- data.frame('a' = c('A','B','C','D','E'),
                   'x' = c("t",2,NA,NA,NA),
                   'y' = c(NA,NA,NA,4,"r"))
```

displayed as

```
'a' 'x' 'y'  
 A   t   NA  
 B   2   NA  
 C  NA   NA  
 D  NA   4  
 E  NA   r
```

to get

```
 'a' 'mycol'  
  A   t  
  B   2  
  C   NA  
  D   4  
  E   r
```

I tried this

```
cbind(data[1], mycol = na.omit(unlist(data[-1])))
```

But it obviously doesn't keep the `NA` row.

Comment: Suggested dupe: [How to implement coalesce in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/903061)

Comment: This case is simple enough you could do `pmin` or `pmax`, e.g., `data$mycol = pmin(data$x, data$y, na.rm = T)`. This scales up to more columns, but it will pick the minimum in the case there are multiple non-missing values. The coalesce answers at the suggested dupe will pick the first non-missing value.

Comment: Other related Q for a simple case like here with only one non-`NA` column; [Combine two fitting string columns to one in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850344/combine-two-fitting-string-columns-to-one-in-r)

Comment: The coalesce solution linked by @Henrik looks like a good general case. You could also use `data.table` to accomplish something similar, but you lose the NAs in favor of 0s. `setDT(data); data[, new := sum(.SD, na.rm=T), by=a, .SDcols= c("x","y"]`

Comment: I added an answer based on this. Thanks all for your comments.

Comment: @Mako212 if you want sums you don't need data table for grouping, just use `rowSums`. The only difference to `pmin` or `pmax` is what happens if there are multiple non-missing values (and the all-NA to 0 as you point out).

Comment: Following OP's edit with two string columns, it is now even more similar to the Q&A I linked to...

Answer (score 3):

You could do it by using `ifelse`, like this:

```
data$mycol <- ifelse(!is.na(data$x), data$x, data$y)

> data

##   a  x  y mycol
## 1 A  1 NA     1
## 2 B  2 NA     2
## 3 C NA NA    NA
## 4 D NA  4     4
## 5 E NA  5     5
```

Comment: Works well on OP's case, but doesn't scale nicely if there are more columns involved...

Answer (score 0):

Going with your logic, you can do following:

```
cbind(data[1], mycol = unlist(apply(data[2:3], 1, function(i) ifelse(
  length(is.na(i))==length(i),
  na.omit(i),
  NA)
)))

#  a mycol
#1 A     1
#2 B     2
#3 C    NA
#4 D     4
#5 E     5
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r) indirectly. Here is a simple solution based on that:

```
data$mycol <- coalesce(data$x, data$y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer to any number of columns, and using the neat `max.col()` function I've discovered thanks to this question:

```
coalesce <- function(value_matrix) {
  value_matrix <- as.matrix(value_matrix)
  first_non_missing <- max.col(!is.na(value_matrix), ties.method = "first")
  indices <- cbind(
    row = seq_len(nrow(value_matrix)),
    col = first_non_missing
  )
  value_matrix[indices]
}

data$mycol <- coalesce(data[, c('x', 'y')])
data
#   a  x  y mycol
# 1 A  1 NA     1
# 2 B  2 NA     2
# 3 C NA NA    NA
# 4 D NA  4     4
# 5 E NA  5     5
```

`max.col(..., ties.method = "first")` returns, for each row, the index of the first column with the maximum value. Since we're using it on a logical matrix, the max is usually `TRUE`. So we'll get the first non-`NA` value for each row. If the entire row is `NA`, then we'll get an `NA` value as desired.

After that, the function uses a matrix of row-column indices to subset the values.

**Edit**

In comparison to [mrip's coalesce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r/19254510#19254510), my `max.col` is slower when there are a few long columns, but faster when there are many short columns.

```
coalesce_reduce <- function(...) {
  Reduce(function(x, y) {
    i <- which(is.na(x))
    x[i] <- y[i]
    x},
    list(...))
}

coalesce_maxcol <- function(...) {
  value_matrix <- cbind(...)
  first_non_missing <- max.col(!is.na(value_matrix), ties.method = "first")
  indices <- cbind(
    row = seq_len(nrow(value_matrix)),
    col = first_non_missing
  )
  value_matrix[indices]
}

set.seed(100)

wide <- replicate(
  1000,
  {sample(c(NA, 1:10), 10, replace = TRUE)},
  simplify = FALSE
)

long <- replicate(
  10,
  {sample(c(NA, 1:10), 1000, replace = TRUE)},
  simplify = FALSE
)

microbenchmark(
  do.call(coalesce_reduce, wide),
  do.call(coalesce_maxcol, wide),
  do.call(coalesce_reduce, long),
  do.call(coalesce_maxcol, long)
)
# Unit: microseconds
#                           expr      min        lq       mean   median       uq      max neval
# do.call(coalesce_reduce, wide) 1879.460 1953.5695 2136.09954 2007.303 2152.654 5284.583   100
# do.call(coalesce_maxcol, wide)  403.604  423.5280  490.40797  433.641  456.583 2543.580   100
# do.call(coalesce_reduce, long)   36.829   41.5085   45.75875   43.471   46.942   79.393   100
# do.call(coalesce_maxcol, long)   80.903   88.1475  175.79337   92.374  101.581 3438.329   100
```

Comment: Any advantages compared to [mrip's lightning-fast answer here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254510/903061)

Comment: Yes, it scales better to more columns.  Adding comparison to answer...