# Replacing one column with the data from another column if the row of column one is empty in R

Tags: r

I have two columns

```
COL1   COL2
SCS    NA
NA     NA
NA     PB
NA     RM
```

Whenever `col1` is `na` and `col2` has a value, I want `col2`'s value to overwrite the `na`.
Whenever `col1` has a value, I want it to stay that value no matter what is in `col2`.

Comment: Answers from this post will be helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850344/coalesce-two-string-columns-with-alternating-missing-values-to-one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace values in `col1` with values in `col2` if a `col1` value is `na

```
data <- data%>% 
  mutate(COL1 = case_when(is.na(COL1) ~ COL2,
                          TRUE ~ as.character(COL1)))
COL1   COL2
SCS    NA
NA     NA
PB     PB
RM     RM
```

Answer (score 3):

With the data.table package and assuming your data.frame is named `df`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[is.na(col1), col1 := col2]
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with `coalesce` by specifying COL1 as first argument followed by COL2 so that if there is any NA in COL1 for a particular row, it will be replaced by the corresponding row from COL2

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data %>%
   mutate(COL1 = coalesce(COL1, COL2))
```

-output

```
data
COL1 COL2
1  SCS <NA>
2 <NA> <NA>
3   PB   PB
4   RM   RM
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(COL1 = c("SCS", NA, NA, NA), COL2 = c(NA, NA, 
"PB", "RM")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```