# in R4.1.2 How can move cells from V2 column to V1 column (IF V1 has empty cell)

Tags: r

In R4.1.2
How can move cells from V2 column to V1 column (IF V1 has empty cell)
(move A3 to column v1)

```
V1  V2  V3
A1  NA  C1
A2  NA  C2
NA  A3  C3
A4  NA  C4
A5  NA  C5
A6  NA  C6
A7  NA  C7
A8  NA  C8
```

my target is

```
V1  V2  V3
A1  NA  C1
A2  NA  C2
A3  NA  C3
A4  NA  C4
A5  NA  C5
A6  NA  C6
A7  NA  C7
A8  NA  C8
```

Comment: With "move" you mean replacing NAs in either `name` or `name2` with Non-NAs from the other column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Coalesce two string columns with alternating missing values to one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850344/coalesce-two-string-columns-with-alternating-missing-values-to-one)