# Merging multiple vectors in R to remove NAs

Tags: r

I have for example vectors like the following:

```
 a= c(1, NA, NA, 2, 3)
 b=c(NA, 1, NA, NA, NA)
 c=c(NA, NA, 5, NA, NA)
```

I wish to merge the three vectors to get

```
  d=c(1,1,5,2,3)
```

Is there a way of doing this without extensive looping? Many thanks :)

Comment: What if there are values in the same position in multiple vectors?

Comment: There should only be one value in each position between all my vectors, the rest should be NA.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/324364) might be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try

```
 rowSums(cbind(a,b,c), na.rm=TRUE)
 #[1] 1 1 5 2 3
```

or

```
mat <- cbind(a,b,c)
mat[cbind(1:nrow(mat),max.col(!is.na(mat)))]
#[1] 1 1 5 2 3
```

Or

```
ind <- which(!is.na(mat), arr.ind=TRUE)
mat[ind[order(ind[,1]),]]
#[1] 1 1 5 2 3
```

Comment: Yeah I tried but it said I had to wait 7 more minutes :P

Answer (score 3):

I would consider `pmin` or `pmax` for a more direct approach given the conditions you describe:

```
pmin(a, b, c, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 5 2 3
pmax(a, b, c, na.rm = TRUE)
# [1] 1 1 5 2 3
```

Comment: @akrun, thanks. I think your approach would still be faster though--I think that `rowSums` is pretty heavily optimized. Oh, and congrats on becoming Legendary! :-)