# missing values filling in R

Tags: r

I want help on R programming to fill col4 
col4=col1, in case col1 is NA then col4=col2, in case col1 and col2 are NA then col4=col3

```
id col1 col2 col3
1   10   NA   NA
2   NA   12   NA
3   NA   NA   13
4   NA   NA   1
5   2    3    NA
```

Answer:

```
id col4
1  10
2  12
3  13
4  1
5  2
```

Comment: I guess, from your expected answer, you want col4 = col1 when col1 is NOT NA, right?

Comment: `df$col4 <- with(df, ifelse(!is.na(col1), col1, ifelse(!is.na(col2), col2, col3)))`

Comment: @zx8754 Is this really a duplicate of the link provided ? The difference is that this asks how to perform a task (the role `coalesce` fills), and the link is to a question about efficient implementation of coalesce. There may be overlap but these are not quite the same.

Comment: @steveb by that logic, if there is a post saying "I want smallest value for the column." is not a duplicate to an existing "How do I use min function in R" ?

Comment: If you want a more appropriate dupe (though the title sucks), try [Nested `ifelse` is the worse, what's the best?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30088919/903061).

Comment: @zx8754 I agree with steveb. Since `coalesce` is not the only method to perform the operation, while the duplicate discusses how to use the `coalesce` function specifically. By analogy, the `min` function is not the only way to calculate the smallest value for the column, but you wouldn't post an answer about the other methods in the "How do I use min function in R" question.

Comment: @zx8754 I don't think that is a correct analogy, I think, to use your example, it is more like "I want smallest value for the column." vs. "how do build an optimized min function".

Comment: @steveb If the OP knew about "coalesce" functionality from any language, then this post wouldn't exist. Quick Google search would point them to the linked post.

Comment: @Gregor Added the link as another target. Thanks.

Comment: @useR I don't understand your comment: "coalesce" is not base, it can be custom function or from dplyr package, as provided in answers in target post.

Comment: @steveb No, linked post OP knows about coalesce function from SQL and shares his attempt in R hoping to improve. Many years later, now we have this function as part of dplyr (again mentioned in target post). And this OP is saying "I am trying to do X", and the correct answer is "You are trying to do coalesce, see this post"

Comment: @zx8754 Now that I read it carefully, I probably mistaken that you (and the dup) were referring to the `coalesce` _function_, instead of _functionality_, hence my argument. As it stands, I think my solution is still valuable in that it takes advantage of explicit splicing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easily done with `coalesce` from `dplyr`. This solution works for N number of columns:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(col4 = coalesce(!!!data[-1]))
```

**Result:**

```
  id col1 col2 col3 col4
1  1   10   NA   NA   10
2  2   NA   12   NA   12
3  3   NA   NA   13   13
4  4   NA   NA    1    1
5  5    2    3   NA    2
```

**Data:**

```
data = read.table(text = "id col1 col2 col3
                1 10 NA NA 
                2 NA 12 NA 
                3 NA NA 13
                4 NA NA 1 
                5 2 3 NA", header = T)
```

**Notes:**

`!!!` shouldn't be confused with the negation operator `!` (understandable confusion). It is an operator that is part of `rlang`, or the `tidyverse` (also available to `dplyr`) which enables *explicit splicing*.

What this means is that instead of inputting the entire data frame into `coalesce` (`coalesce(data[-1])`), I am separating the columns of `data[-1]` (or elements of the list) and have each element as an input to `coalesce`. So this:

```
coalesce(!!!data[-1])
```

is actually equivalent to this:

```
coalesce(col1, col2, col3)
```

The advantage of writing it this way is that you don't have to know the column names nor how many columns there are to begin with.

Comment: @steveb good question, see my explaination

Comment: That's what happens when I skip too quickly :-)

Comment: Not sure why this answer gets downvoted. Would be nice if the downvoter can comment on things I can improve on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr::coalesce`, or any of the answers at [How to implement coalesce in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/903061):

```
xx$col4 = with(xx, coalesce(col1, col2, col3))
```

Comment: Why not hammer as duplicate?

Comment: Thank Gregor. This is working