# Cannot copy one column's values to another

Tags: r

I am creating two data frames and then merging them into a third:

```
dat <- data.frame(code = c("A11", "B22", "C33"),
                  age = c(NA, NA, 12),
                  sex = c(NA, NA, 2),
                  more = c(7, 4, 9),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

age.and.sex <- read.table(textConnection("
code age sex
A11 15 2
B22 10 1
"), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

joined <- merge(dat, age.and.sex, by="code", all.x=TRUE)

joined
  code age.x sex.x more age.y sex.y
1  A11    NA    NA    7    15     2
2  B22    NA    NA    4    10     1
3  C33    12     2    9    NA    NA
```

Now, when I try to copy values from the two new columns ("age.y", "sex.y") into the two old ones ("age.x", "sex.y"), this works for one column, but for the other I get a curious warning:

```
joined[is.na(joined$age.x)]$age.x <- joined$age.y
joined[is.na(joined$sex.x)]$sex.x <- joined$sex.y
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, is.na(joined$sex.x), value = list(code = c("A11",  :
  provided 5 variables to replace 4 variables
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You indexed the columns of your dataframe, and, by accident, your index was a multiple of the number of columns. look at what you indexed:

```
> joined[is.na(joined$age.x)]
  code age.x more age.y
1  A11    NA    7    15
2  B22    NA    4    10
3  C33    12    9    NA
```

I guess what you want to do is the following:

```
joined[is.na(joined$age.x),]$age.x <- joined$age.y[is.na(joined$age.x)]
joined[is.na(joined$sex.x),]$sex.x <- joined$sex.y[is.na(joined$sex.x)]
```

Comment: I guess `joined$age.x[is.na(joined$age.x)]` might be more efficient.

Comment: I tried to stay close to the OPs solution to keep it more instructive. I agree that your way or the one joran suggested would be preferred.

Comment: @nicola Why is that more efficient?

Comment: @what Extracting a column from a `data.frame` is a relatively cheap operation, since in most cases internally is enough to get the pointer of that column. Subsetting might be more expensive, and surely subsetting a `data.frame` is more expensive than just a vector.. By `joined[is.na(joined$age.x),]$age.x` R must subset, create a completely new `data.frame` and from it extract the given column. If you invert the order, you extract the column first (fast) and then subset just a column, eliminating the overhead due to the construction of a `data.frame`.

Comment: Thank you, @nicola. I understand.

Answer (score 4):

Both of those column "replacements" are completely wrong, but let's focus on the second one, since the first failed in a silent way more or less by accident.

So let's walk through the line

```
joined[is.na(joined$sex.x)]$sex.x <- joined$sex.y
```

step by step.

So start with what the `is.na()` piece is going to return:

```
is.na(joined$sex.x)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

A boolean vector of length three. Ok, I guess. Now what happens when we essentially do `joined[c(T,T,F)]`?

```
> joined[is.na(joined$sex.x)]
  code age.x more age.y
1  A11    15    7    15
2  B22    10    4    10
3  C33    NA    9    NA
```

I bet you weren't expecting that! R thinks you are selecting columns, recycles the boolean vector and selects columns 1, 2, 4 and 5. Notice that `sex.x` isn't present at all:

```
> joined[is.na(joined$sex.x)]$sex.x
NULL
```

At this point it should be totally clear why you got a warning. You were attempting to assign to something that did not exist.

The first attempt failed as well (it copied the `NA` from the `.y` column, which is probably not what you wanted). But you were just lucky that the column you wanted was present at all.

More generally, replacement and subsetting is probably a fragile way to do this, you are probably looking for a [coalesce](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/324364) function.