# Replace missing values with a value from another column

Tags: r, missing-data

If I have:

```
s <- data.frame(ID=c(191, 282, 202, 210), Group=c("", "A", "", "B"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
s
   ID Group
1 191      
2 282     A
3 202      
4 210     B
```

I can replace the empty cells with N like this:

```
ds$Group[ds$Group==""]<-"N"

s
   ID Group
1 191     N 
2 282     A
3 202     N
4 210     B
```

But I would need to replace the empty cells with a value from another column. How can I accomplish this?:

```
s
   ID Group Group2
1 191     D      D
2 282     A      G
3 202     G      G
4 210     B      D
```

Comment: `ds$Group[ds$Group==""] <- ds$Group2[ds$Group==""]`

Comment: Relevant post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820 `ds$Group <- coalesce2(ds$Group, ds$Group2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ifelse(test, yes, no)` is a handy function to do just that, and it can be used on vectors. Using your last data.frame:

```
s <- data.frame(ID = c(191, 282, 202, 210),
    Group = c("", "A", "", "B"),
    Group2 = c("D", "G", "G", "D"))

s$Group <- ifelse(test = s$Group != "", yes = s$Group, no = s$Group2)
```

The first argument is the test. For each value in the vector, if the `test` is true, then it will take the value in `yes`, otherwise it will take the value in `no`.

Answer (score 6):

We can use `data.table` to assign the values in "Group2" to "Group" where the "Group" is `""` specified in the "i" condition.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(s)[Group=="", Group:= Group2]
```

As the assignment happens in place, it is considered to be efficient.