# Overwrite single corresponding elements between two lists

Tags: r, overwrite

I have a rather small question:

Imagine two lists "default" and "example", each is composed of 5 elements with identical names ("p1","p2,"p3","p4,"p5).

In case "p-values" of example have a value assigned to it, this value will remain.

In case a "p-value" has no value assigned to it (NA), the corresponding "p-value" of default should used to replace the gap.

I know you could loop through each element with a for loop and construct an if-loop within the for-loop but is there maybe a more elegant solution?

Here is an example case:

```
example=list(p1=2,p2=3,p3=4,p4=NA,p5=NA)
default=list(p1=26,p2=34,p3=43,p4=11,p5=98)
```

Comment: Please share your data instead of describing it.

Comment: subset and replace using `is.na()`. soething like `example[ is.na(example)]`

Comment: Maybe related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
# assign matching p-value from default
example[ is.na(example) ] <- default[ is.na(example) ]

# result
example

# $p1
# [1] 2
# 
# $p2
# [1] 3
# 
# $p3
# [1] 4
# 
# $p4
# [1] 11
# 
# $p5
# [1] 98
```