# Fill NAs in dataframe with a matching dataframe merge in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have three data frames. One 'main' data frame to which I want to merge the other two sub data frames.

```
main = data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:5], b = round(rnorm(5),2))

a     b
A  0.41
B -1.06
C -0.65
D -1.27
E  1.03

sub1 = data.frame(a = LETTERS[2:4], c = sample(c(100, 200, 300), 3, replace=T))

a   c
B 200
C 200
D 200

sub2 = data.frame(a = LETTERS[c(1,5)], c = sample(c(999, 888), 2, replace=T))

a   c
A 999
E 888
```

In the first merge, I want to merge `sub1` to `main` via `"a"` and this works.

```
merged1 = merge(main, sub1, by="a", all.x=T)

a     b   c
A  0.41  NA
B -1.06 300
C -0.65 300
D -1.27 100
E  1.03  NA
```

Now I want to join/merge the `sub2` to `merged1`. In my case, the values provided by `sub2` substitute the NAs in column c. Specifically I want to replace these NAs with the values from `sub2`. I tried this (and other arguments for `all.x`, `all.y`:

```
merge(merged1, sub2, by="a", all.x=T)

a     b c.x c.y
A  0.41  NA 999
B -1.06 300  NA
C -0.65 300  NA
D -1.27 100  NA
E  1.03  NA 999
```

How can I get this to be only one column c with the merge?

Comment: Could you please 1) use set a seed number when generating these data.frames so that they're reproducible. 2) be consistent in naming conventions...you create data frames "sub1" and "main" but then use "df_main" and "df_sub1" in the merge. 3) check your example for accuracy. It appears df_sub1 and sub1 are different since the latter contains 300 but the former contains only 200.

Comment: Just `rbind(df_sub1, df_sub2)` and merge to that instead of the individual little merges. You may need to convert the factor column to character to successfully `rbind`.

Comment: I think the only other option is to post-process with a [coalesce-like function](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/903061).

Comment: Perhaps `match` is also an option: `merged1$c[ match(sub2$a, merged1$a)] <- sub2$c`. (Note that your example is a little inconsistent... `df_sub1`, `sub1`, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Note: My seed was set, so the results are different than those in the question.*

If you bind your sub1 or sub2 together, you can do it all in one merge.

```
set.seed(42)

main = data.frame(a = LETTERS[1:5], b = round(rnorm(5),2))

sub1 = data.frame(a = LETTERS[2:4], c = sample(c(100, 200, 300), 3, replace=T))

sub2 = data.frame(a = LETTERS[c(1,5)], c = sample(c(999, 888), 2, replace=T))

#Create one data frame
all_sub <- rbind(sub1,sub2)

merged <- merge(main, all_sub, by="a", all.x=T)
```

The output is as expected:

```
> merged
  a     b   c
1 A  1.37 999
2 B -0.56 200
3 C  0.36 300
4 D  0.63 300
5 E  0.40 999
```