# Replace the values

Tags: r

I have two variables transID and transid

```
transID        transid
fsdfsdgls         NA
dfdsfgdsgs     mksdjfl
werwer         fgsdsdg
xcvcxvx           NA
```

I want the output like

```
transID         transid
fsdfsdgls          NA 
mksdjfl         mksdjfl 
fgsdsdg         fgsdsdg
xcvcxvx           NA
```

I want to replace the value in transID with transid when it is not NA

Comment: Some form of a [coalesce](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r) function may be useful for returning the first non-NA value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to do this in a faster way as the `:=` does this in place.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), specify the logical condition in 'i' (`!is.na(transid)`) and assign (`:=`) 'transid' values corresponding to the TRUE values in 'i' to 'transID' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(transid), transID := transid]
df
#     transID transid
#1: fsdfsdgls      NA
#2:   mksdjfl mksdjfl
#3:   fgsdsdg fgsdsdg
#4:   xcvcxvx      NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(transID = c("fsdfsdgls", "dfdsfgdsgs", "werwer", 
"xcvcxvx"), transid = c(NA, "mksdjfl", "fgsdsdg", NA)),
.Names = c("transID", "transid"), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: I tried this setDT(la2)[!is.na(la2$transid), la2$transId := la2$transid]                  Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(la2), !is.na(la2$transid), `:=`(la2$transId,  : 
  LHS of := isn't column names ('character') or positions ('integer' or 'numeric')

Comment: @63549  Updated with the data I used.  Do you have `factor` columns?  I used `character` columns. If they are `factor` columns, convert to `character` i.e. `df[] <- lapply(df, as.character)` and then apply the code

Answer (score 2):

Since there are only two choices, you can use a single `ifelse()`:

```
df <- data.frame(transID=c('fsdfsdgls','dfdsfgdsgs','werwer','xcvcxvx'),transid=c(NA,'mksdjfl','fgsdsdg',NA),stringsAsFactors=F);
df$transID <- ifelse(is.na(df$transid),df$transID,df$transid);
df;
##     transID transid
## 1 fsdfsdgls    <NA>
## 2   mksdjfl mksdjfl
## 3   fgsdsdg fgsdsdg
## 4   xcvcxvx    <NA>
```

---

Another possibility, by precomputing which indexes require replacement:

```
i <- which(!is.na(df$transid));
df$transID[i] <- df$transid[i];
df;
##     transID transid
## 1 fsdfsdgls    <NA>
## 2   mksdjfl mksdjfl
## 3   fgsdsdg fgsdsdg
## 4   xcvcxvx    <NA>
```

Comment: I tried using the above code in dataset.It showing an error                               Error in ifelse(is.na(la2$transid), la2$transID, la2$transid) : 
  replacement has length zero
In addition: Warning message:
In rep(yes, length.out = length(ans)) :
  'x' is NULL so the result will be NULL