# Merge/Join prioritizing non-missing values

Tags: r, join, dataframe, merge, dplyr

**Is there a merging function that prioritizes non-missing values from common variables?**

Consider the following example.

First we generate two data.frames with the same IDs but complementary missing values on a particular varuiable:

```
set.seed(1)
missings  <- sample.int(6, 3)
df1  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA)
df2  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA)
df1$V1[missings]  <- rnorm(3)
df2$V1[setdiff(1:6, missings)]  <- rnorm(3)
```

Applying `merge` or any of the `join` functions from the `dplyr` package produces results similar to the below:

```
> merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID')
  ID      V1.x       V1.y
1  a        NA -1.5399500
2  b 1.3297993         NA
3  c 0.4146414         NA
4  d        NA -0.9285670
5  e        NA -0.2947204
6  f 1.2724293         NA
```

We'd like to join these two data.frames in a "smarter" way that ignores missing values in one data.frame when not missing in the other to obtain the below output:

```
> output <- df1
> output$V1[is.na(df1$V1)]  <- df2$V1[!(is.na(df2$V1))]
> output
  ID         V1
1  a -1.5399500
2  b  1.3297993
3  c  0.4146414
4  d -0.9285670
5  e -0.2947204
6  f  1.2724293
```

We can assume that `df1` and `df2` have totally complementary missing values of `V1`.

#### EDIT

A solution that would work for an arbitrary number of variables would be ideal.

Comment: But what if they aren't complementary? If an ID *does* have non-missing values in both df1 and df2 do you want to retain both, or prioritize one? SQL would typically have you prioritize one using the `coalesce` function - [see here for implementations of `coalesce` in R](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19253820/903061). Of course it will still work if they are complementary as well.

Comment: @Gregor The devel version of `dplyr` has an implementation of `coalsece` so you can simply do `dplyr::coalesce(df1, df2)`:

Comment: Correct--you *would* want to retain both in such a situation. That's not my situation, but `coalesce` is sounding right--thank you both. Perhaps a more general (better?) question would ask how to implement a merge that selects one of two values based on some condition, not just missingness...

Comment: @StevenBeaupré I think (hope!) that it is more analogous to SQL and works on vectors not data frames. The idiom I'd hope for would be `full_join(df1, df2, by = 'ID') %>% mutate(V1 = coalesce(V1.x, V1.y)`

Comment: @Buckminster I think it's two operations - a merge/join and a coalesce. Best to treat them as two steps.

Comment: @Gregor got it. The issue that comes to mind is that there may be many such variables (my current situation) and it would be great to automate the coalescing!

Comment: That's a good point. In a case like this though when you're not really joining something like `na.omit(rbind(df1, df2))` works as well (equivalently to `merge(na.omit(df1), na.omit(df2), by = 'ID')`, which you more-or-less show). Not sure why that method is unsatisfactory. Are there potentially missing values in other columns you want to keep around?

Comment: @Gregor exactly--there are missing values in other columns that are meaningful. I think my toy example might be a little too simplified to communicate all of the issues at hand.

Comment: @Gregor That would be the idiomatic way to proceed, indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to the very helpful comments of @Gregor and @StevenBeaupré, I came up with a solution using `coalesce.na` from the `kimisc` package that extends to arbitrary numbers of variables:

```
mapply(function(x,y) coalesce.na(x,y), df1$V1, df2$V1)
[1] -1.5399500  1.3297993  0.4146414 -0.9285670 -0.2947204  1.2724293
```

Notice that `df1$V1` and `df2$V1` could be replaced lists of variables, allowing for something like:

```
> set.seed(1)
> missings  <- sample.int(6, 3)
> df1  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6],
+                    V1 = NA,
+                    V2 = NA)
> df2  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6],
+                    V1 = NA,
+                    V2 = NA)
> df1$V1[missings]  <- rnorm(3)
> df2$V1[setdiff(1:6, missings)]  <- rnorm(3)
> df1$V2[setdiff(1:6, missings)]  <- rnorm(3)
> df2$V2[missings]  <- rnorm(3)

> cbind(df1, df2)
  ID        V1           V2 ID         V1         V2
1  a        NA -0.005767173  a -1.5399500         NA
2  b 1.3297993           NA  b         NA -0.7990092
3  c 0.4146414           NA  c         NA -0.2894616
4  d        NA  2.404653389  d -0.9285670         NA
5  e        NA  0.763593461  e -0.2947204         NA
6  f 1.2724293           NA  f         NA -1.1476570

> dfMerged <- merge(df1, df2, by = 'ID')
> xList <- dfMerged[grep("\\.x$", names(dfMerged))]
> yList <- dfMerged[grep("\\.y$", names(dfMerged))]

> mapply(function(x,y) coalesce.na(x,y), xList, yList)
           V1.x         V2.x
[1,] -1.5399500 -0.005767173
[2,]  1.3297993 -0.799009249
[3,]  0.4146414 -0.289461574
[4,] -0.9285670  2.404653389
[5,] -0.2947204  0.763593461
[6,]  1.2724293 -1.147657009
```

A full solution would thus look something like:

```
library(kimisc)
smartMergeList <- function(dfList, idVar) {
    merged <- Reduce(x = dfList, 
                     f = function(x,y) merge(x, y, by = idVar, all = T))
    xList <- merged[grep("\\.x$", names(merged))]
    yList <- merged[grep("\\.y$", names(merged))]
    merged[names(xList)] <- mapply(function(x,y) coalesce.na(x,y),
                            xList, yList)
    merged[names(yList)] <- NULL
    merged
})
```

I would love to see something prettier though!

Answer (score 2):

If avoiding specifying the columns is the only issue with `output$V1[is.na(df1$V1)]  <- df2$V1[!(is.na(df2$V1))]`, then you just need to use `na.omit()` instead of specifying the variables individually. We can also do this only for overlapping columns.

Let's modify the original data so that the columns aren't a perfect overlap and the extra columns have some data we want to keep:

```
set.seed(1)

missings  <- sample.int(6, 3)
df1  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA, V2 = c(NA, 2, 3, NA, 5, 6))
df2  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA)
df1$V1[missings]  <- rnorm(3)
df2$V1[setdiff(1:6, missings)]  <- rnorm(3)

# now df1 looks like this:
df1
#   ID        V1 V2
# 1  a        NA NA
# 2  b 1.3297993  2
# 3  c 0.4146414  3
# 4  d        NA NA
# 5  e        NA  5
# 6  f 1.2724293  6


common_cols = intersect(names(df1), names(df2))
result = na.omit(rbind(df1[common_cols], df2[common_cols]))
result = merge(result, df1, all.x = T)
result = merge(result, df2, all.x = T)
  # the merges are only necessary if there are additional columns to pick up

result
# ID           V1 V2
# 1  a -1.5399500 NA
# 2  b  1.3297993  2
# 3  c  0.4146414  3
# 4  d -0.9285670 NA
# 5  e -0.2947204 NA
# 6  f  1.2724293  6
```

Comment: Hmmm, I see I still have a problem because the V2 value for ID `e` got lost. Probably the solution is to treat the ID column separately from the other `common_col` columns and merge on `ID` including only non-common columns...

Answer (score 1):

Based on the discussion and answers above, here is my take using `dplyr`. Not the cleanest code, yes I do have `suppressWarnings()`.

**For the reproducible example by OP:**

```
set.seed(1)
missings  <- sample.int(6, 3)
df1  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA)
df2  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA)
df1$V1[missings]  <- rnorm(3)
df2$V1[setdiff(1:6, missings)]  <- rnorm(3)
```

Simple solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
coalesce <- function(...) {
  apply((...), 1, function(x) {
    x[which(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))))[1]]
  })
}

full_join(df1, df2, by = 'ID') %>% mutate(V1 = coalesce(.)) %>% select(.,ID,V1)

  ID         V1
1  a -1.5399500
2  b  1.3297993
3  c  0.4146414
4  d -0.9285670
5  e -0.2947204
6  f  1.2724293
```

**For a general solution with multiple (here shown with 3) variables:**

```
set.seed(1)
df1  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA, V2 = NA, V3 = NA)
df2  <- data.frame(ID = letters[1:6], V1 = NA, V2 = NA, V3 = NA)
df1$V1[sample.int(6, 3)]  <- rnorm(3)
df2$V1[setdiff(1:6, sample.int(6, 3))]  <- rnorm(3)
df1$V2[sample.int(6, 3)]  <- rnorm(3)
df2$V2[setdiff(1:6, sample.int(6, 3))]  <- rnorm(3)
df1$V3[sample.int(6, 3)]  <- rnorm(3)
df2$V3[setdiff(1:6, sample.int(6, 3))]  <- rnorm(3)
```

Same `coalesce()` function, more elaborate `dplyr` logic:

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
coalesce <- function(...) {
  apply((...), 1, function(x) {
    x[which(!is.na(suppressWarnings(as.numeric(x))))[1]]
  })
}

full_join(df1, df2, by = "ID") %>% 
  melt(., id.vars = "ID") %>%
  mutate(var = substr(as.character(variable),0,2)) %>%
  group_by(var,value) %>% 
  dcast(.,ID + var ~ variable, value.var = "value") %>%
  mutate(c = coalesce(.)) %>%
  dcast(.,ID ~ var, value.var = "c")

  ID         V1         V2          V3
1  a -1.5399500  0.3898432        <NA>
2  b -0.9285670 -0.3053884  0.80418951
3  c -0.8356286       <NA>   0.5939013
4  d  0.1836433 -0.4115108 -0.05710677
5  e       <NA>       <NA>   0.8212212
6  f -0.6264538  1.5117812   0.9189774
```

The `coalesce()` function picks the first non-NA value (if it exists). You can choose `max` or something else per your problem. The `ID` column or any other columns in the merged dataset must be non-numeric. I hope this is some help toward solving your real problem.

Comment: I like that your solution generalizes to conditions other than missingness, i.e., replacing `which(!is.na())` with `which.max` would select largest of all values.

Comment: I have not tested it other than the dataset in this question. Let me know if it works for the multiple variables in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible `data.table` way to do it:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1); setDT(df2);

df1[df2, V1 := ifelse(is.na(V1), i.V1, V1), on = "ID"]

df1
#    ID         V1
# 1:  a -1.5399500
# 2:  b  1.3297993
# 3:  c  0.4146414
# 4:  d -0.9285670
# 5:  e -0.2947204
# 6:  f  1.2724293
```

Comment: Cheers! But can you think of a method that avoids manually specifying the variables? There might be arbitrarily many!