# What is the best way to clean a data.frame in which row values are ordered properly, but are arbitrarily separated by NA columns?

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Occasionally, I need to clean *very* messy datasets, which are the result of importing a pdf table to a spreadsheet. When the pdf file is converted, all of the columns remain in the correct order (in relation to each other), but blank columns are scattered arbitrarily between them.

Here is a greatly simplified example.

```
data <- data.frame(
  W = sample(1:10),
  X = c("yes","no"," ","yes","no"," "," ","no","yes"," "),
  Y = c(" "," "," "," "," ","no","no"," "," ","yes"),
  Z = c(" "," ","no"," "," "," "," "," "," "," ")
)
data$X <- gsub(" ", NA, data$X)
data$Y <- gsub(" ", NA, data$Y)
data$Z <- gsub(" ", NA, data$Z)
```

This results in:

```
> data
    W    X    Y    Z
1   6  yes <NA> <NA>
2   4   no <NA> <NA>
3   3 <NA> <NA>   no
4   5  yes <NA> <NA>
5   9   no <NA> <NA>
6   1 <NA>   no <NA>
7   7 <NA>   no <NA>
8   8   no <NA> <NA>
9  10  yes <NA> <NA>
10  2 <NA>  yes <NA>
```

I want to get this:

```
    W    X
1   6   yes
2   4   no
3   3   no
4   5   yes
5   9   no
6   1   no
7   7   no
8   8   no
9   10  yes
10  2   yes
```

How can I best accomplish this? I need code that can accommodate many versions of this problem, including successive columns with NA values before the column containing the desired values. If I could just remove each individual cell with NA values, while shifting remaining values left, that would work. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to collapse all the columns with `NA` into one column that has only known values?

Comment: See also [How to implement coalesce efficiently in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r) and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

One option in `base` R is to get the array indices of the non `NA` values using `which()`, then subset the dataset according to the resulting matrix of indices sorted by row number.

```
indices <- which(!is.na(data[,-1]), arr.ind = TRUE)
data$X <- data[,-1][indices[order(indices[,1]),]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using matrix subsetting in base R, we can select the non missing values as follows. The outer `cbind` constructs the two column data.frame. The second column is constructed by matrix subsetting. A matrix is fed to `data` which identify the desired elements. Here, the rows are selected with `seq_len` and the columns are selected using `max.col` to find the column with TRUE for each row. That is, the column that does not have NA in `data[-1]`. A 1 is added to adjust for the initial missing column.

```
cbind(data[1L], response=data[cbind(seq_len(nrow(data)), max.col(!is.na(data[-1L])) + 1L)])
    W response
1  10      yes
2   7       no
3   8       no
4   5      yes
5   1       no
6   2       no
7   6       no
8   4       no
9   3      yes
10  9      yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `coalesce` from dplyr,

```
Reduce(dplyr::coalesce, data[-1])
 [1] "yes" "no"  "no"  "yes" "no"  "no"  "no"  "no"  "yes" "yes"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is `pmax`

```
cbind(data[1], response = do.call(pmax, c(data[-1], na.rm = TRUE)))
#    W response
#1   3      yes
#2   6       no
#3  10       no
#4   2      yes
#5   5       no
#6   7       no
#7   8       no
#8   1       no
#9   4      yes
#10  9      yes
```