# r simple way to merge 2 columns with not NA values

Tags: r, dataframe

How to merge this into 1 column?

`df <- data.frame(a = c("1", "2", NA, NA), b = c(NA, NA, "3", "4"), c = c(NA, "5", "6", NA), stringsAsFactors = F)`

I just want to get All values from b into a without NA. So a should be: "1", "2", "3", "4". (Now is the need of choosing columns from more than 2 in df)

This works not good:
`df$a <- df$b[!is.na(df$b)]`

Comment: [Relevant...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r)

Comment: See linked post, which has many solutions which work with multiple columns. For example, as suggested by akrun below, try: `dplyr::coalesce(df$a, df$b, df$c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `pmax`

```
df$a <- do.call(pmax, c(df, na.rm = TRUE))
```

---

Or with `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(a = coalesce(a,b))
#  a    b
#1 1 <NA>
#2 2 <NA>
#3 3    3
#4 4    4
```

Comment: Ok, Thanks. This `coalesce` function does the thing.