# "tidyr like" fill na from different column

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I've a data frame with missing values is some column (who doesn't).
For example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(2,NA,4), y = 5:7)
df
   x y
1  2 5
2 NA 6
3  4 7
```

I would like to replace the missing value with a value of a different column. Obviously there are a lot of ways to do so, for example:

```
 df %>%
   mutate(x = ifelse(is.na(x), y, x))

  x y
1 2 5
2 6 6
3 4 7
```

However, I am looking for something more elegant, like

```
df %>% fill(x,y)
```

but couldn't find anything. Does something like this exist?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of ifelse you could use dplyr's `coalesce` function, i.e. `df %>% mutate(x = coalesce(x, as.numeric(y)))`

Comment: If there was a pure `tidyr` solution, I bet it would have appeared here: [How to implement coalesce efficiently in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to change values in a single column, keeping the same number of rows. The tidyverse way to do that is `dplyr::mutate`, and the tidyverse implementation of the specific operation you want is `dplyr::coalesce`, as docendo discimus suggested:

```
df %>% mutate(x = coalesce(x, y))
```

Things would be *less tidy and less consistent* if there was a single function that combined these two steps, as it is not the whole data frame being operated on, just a single column. It would also be less flexible, as `coalesce` can be used on vectors whether or not they are in a data frame, which is good!

---

(I actually dislike `tidyr::fill` - I suppose it is consistent because it operates on all columns of the data frame, but I would prefer that it took a single vector and was typically used inside `mutate`. `mutate_all(fill)` would be easy enough to do the whole data frame. So I end up still relying `zoo::na.locf` for general use.)

Comment: Thanks you @Gregor, I was not familiar with `coalesce` and it indeed addresses my need.

Answer (score 3):

I am aware I don't fully answer the question, but I find the standard data frame way not so bad :

```
df$x[is.na(df$x)] <- df$y[is.na(df$x)]
```

and the data.table way quite simple and elegant:

```
df[is.na(x),x := y]
```

Comment: Thanks you @denis, I agree the data.table way is simple and elegant, but in genral I'm more a tidyverse user

Answer (score 0):

try this, good luck

```
df <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) if(any(is.na(x))) rep(x[!is.na(x)], 2) else x))
as.data.frame(df)
```

Comment: This will convert to a matrix and thus destroy any `class` differences present in the data frame.