# Replace column with another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to replace the value of column Name.x with value from Name.y with condition if it is not NA (empty rows)

```
Name.x  Name.y
US      NA
Germany NA
Germany France
Canada  NA
Italy     Morocco
Austria Belgium
```

Result:

```
Name.x
US
Germany
France
Canada
Morocco
Belgium
```

Comment: do a `coalesce` i.e. `library(dplyr);d1 %>% mutate(Name.x = coalesce(Name.x, Name.y)) %>% select(Name.x)`

Comment: If it is only 2 columns then try: `df1$Name.x <- ifelse(!is.na(df1$Name.y), df1$Name.y, df1$Name.x)`

Comment: it is a big dataset... this is just an example to make it simplier

Comment: Data can be big, but are you comparing only 2 columns or more? If more, then use coalesce as suggested by akrun.

Comment: i only want name.x column in this dataframe1 to  be basically overwritten by dataframe2 only with condition that it is not empty.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement coalesce efficiently in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r)

Comment: @akrun I think it should be `coalesce(Name.y, Name.x)`, going by the example provided.

Comment: @Aramis7d  Could be, I think there are some edits in the example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

Your data.frame

```
 db1<-data.frame(Name.x=c("US","Germany"),
                 Name.y=c(NA,"France"))
   db1
   Name.x Name.y
      US   <NA>
 Germany France
```

Columns names to analyze/substitute

```
coldb1_NA<-"Name.y"
coldb_toSub<-"Name.x"
```

Substitution

```
db2<-db1
db2[,coldb_toSub]<-as.character(db1[,coldb_toSub])
db2[!is.na(db1[,coldb1_NA]),coldb_toSub]<-as.character(db1[!is.na(db1[,coldb1_NA]),coldb1_NA])
```

Your output

```
db2
  Name.x Name.y
1     US   <NA>
2 France France
```

Comment: it is a big datasets with different other names ... is there a way to wrtie something like this ... total_split[, "Name.x"] <- total_split[, "Name.y"=!'']
 ?

Comment: This code is not relied to the names of the countries present inside che two columns (Name.x, Name.y). You want that this code works also on other columns?

Comment: Added a general solution with parametrization of columns names

Comment: what the db1 and db2 stand for ?

Comment: i replace  db1 and db2  by the name of my dataframe and basically the result i got , is that Name.y overworte Name.x including empty rows as well ...

Comment: Name.x in db2 replaces Name.x in db1 where Name.y in db1 is NA. Isn't this what you want?

Comment: yes exactly... but I dont want NA in Name.y to overwrite  Name.x ... this mean  Name.y overwrite  Name.x ONLY when Name.y have a name ..

Comment: Ok, look at the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Example data:

```
a <- data.frame("Name.x" = c("US", "Germany","Germany", "Canada", "Italy", "Austria"),  "Name.y" = c(NA, NA, "France", NA, "Morocco", "Belgium"))
```

Solution:

```
a$Name.x <- ifelse(is.na(a$Name.y), as.character(a$Name.x), as.character(a$Name.y))
```

Comment: Welcome to `stackoverflow`.
Please always try to explain what you're doing in the code. It's not really helpful to just submit unformatted code without any explanations.

Comment: This is a good answer. The downvote is a bit harsh here especially considering that the code is self explanatory.