# Replace missing values by merging with another row

Tags: r, data.table

I read data from different sources into a data.table. Two sources supply different variables for the same time step.

How can I replace the missing variables by the other source (row)?

```
   Here is a minimal example: 
   (gg = data.table(SourceCode = c(1,1,2,2), time = c(1,2,1,2), LE = c(10,10,NA,NA), R = c(NA,NA,20,30)))
   SourceCode time LE  R
1:          1    1 10 NA
2:          1    2 10 NA
3:          2    1 NA 20
4:          2    2 NA 30

> # rename SourceCode
> gg[SourceCode == 1, SourceCode := 2 ]
> gg
   SourceCode time LE  R
1:          2    1 10 NA
2:          2    2 10 NA
3:          2    1 NA 20
4:          2    2 NA 30
```

Desired output:

```
   SourceCode time LE  R
1:          2    1 10 20
2:          2    2 10 30
```

Comment: Please, provide code that you have already tried to do. For now there is no any issue in your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you seem to be working with `data.table`s, here is a `data.table` solution

```
unique(gg[, `:=`(LE = LE[!is.na(LE)], R = R[!is.na(R)]), by = time], by = "time")
#   SourceCode time LE  R
#1:          1    1 10 20
#2:          1    2 10 30
```

Or for the second source

```
unique(gg[, `:=`(LE = LE[!is.na(LE)], R = R[!is.na(R)]), by = time], by = "time", fromLast = T)
#   SourceCode time LE  R
#1:          2    1 10 20
#2:          2    2 10 30
```

Since `SourceCode` seems not relevant anymore (you summarise across different `SourceCode`s) you could also do

```
gg[, lapply(.SD, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), by = time, .SDcols = 3:4]
#   time LE  R
#1:    1 10 20
#2:    2 10 30
```

Answer (score 1):

I had [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50619906/update-existing-data-frame-with-values-from-another-one-if-missing) recently and discovered `dplyr::coalesce()`:

The simple solution would be:

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(
  filter(gg, SourceCode == 2),
  filter(gg, SourceCode == 1)
)
  SourceCode time LE  R
1          2    1 10 20
2          2    2 10 30
```

But more generalisable:

```
do.call(coalesce, split(gg, gg$SourceCode))
   SourceCode time LE  R
1:          1    1 10 20
2:          1    2 10 30
```

If you want to base of the second source (or the last source) you could do:

```
do.call(coalesce, rev(split(gg, gg$SourceCode)))
   SourceCode time LE  R
1:          2    1 10 20
2:          2    2 10 30
```

Answer (score 0):

An option:

```
library(tidyverse)
dd %>% 
    gather(var, val, -SourceCode, -time) %>% 
    na.omit(val) %>% 
    spread(var, val)

#   SourceCode time LE  R
# 1          2    1 10 20
# 2          2    2 10 30
```

Or another option based on grouping

```
dd %>% 
    group_by(SourceCode, time) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(LE:R), .funs = funs(.[which(!is.na(.))]))

#   SourceCode time LE  R
# 1          2    1 10 20
# 2          2    2 10 30
```

Note that I only add the SourceCode in the `group_by` call to keep it in the summary. If you do not need that column, you could omit that.