# How to keep column B in row x if column A in row x has value

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
ID     COL01_A  COL01_B   COL02_A COL02_B  ... COL12_A  COL12_B
1      01       19990101  03      20000101 ... FF       ""
2      03       20170810  FA      20120303 ... ""       ""
3      GG       19940508  DD      20000101 ... 03       20060808
4      03       20180101  09      20000101 ... ""       ""
5      GF       20171212  03      19990101 ... 02       20190101
```

The values in the columns type A dictate wether the value in column type B is the one i'm looking for. In this case the interest is for values "03". There are twelve pairs of this columns. As seen in the example from COL01_A/COL01_B to COL12_A/COL12_B

I was looking for a way to generate a new column (lets call it COL_X) where the value of column type B is reflected only if it's twin column of type A has the "03" value. For the example presented above, the desired result would be something like this.

```
ID  COL01_A  COL01_B   COL02_A COL02_B  ... COL12_A  COL12_B   COL_X
1   01       19990101  03      20000101 ... FF       ""        20000101
2   03       20170810  FA      20120303 ... ""       ""        20170810     
3   GG       19940508  DD      20000101 ... 03       20060808  20060808
4   03       20180101  09      20000101 ... ""       ""        20180101  
5   GF       20171212  03      19990101 ... 02       20190101  19990101
```

Right now i've solved my problem using a brutally long nested ifelse statement, which is not exactly readable nor is it a good practice (in my opinion). In terms of efficiency, it's fast, but i suppose it's only because the data is not too massive. I also found another solution using `do.call(pmax(...))`, But this solution requires me to clean the data frame (using ifelse statements) and creating an auxiliary dataframe with all the other information per row.

Is there a way to accomplish this in the least lines of code possible and/or not using auxiliary structures? If the solution uses data.table or dplyr it would be great.

Basic reproducible example:

```
ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
DATA <- c('xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz','xyz','zxy')
COL01_A<- c('01','03','GG','03','GF')
COL01_B<- c('19990101','20170810','19940508','20180101','20171212')
COL02_A<- c('03','FA','DD','09','03')
COL02_B<- c('20000101','20120303','20000101','20000101','19990101')
COL03_A<- c('FF','','03','','02')
COL03_B<- c('','','20060808','','20190101')

df <- data.frame(ID, DATA, COL01_A,COL01_B,COL02_A,COL02_B,COL03_A,COL03_B)
```

if there are several "03" values the COL_X should have ""

Comment: @RonakShah if there are several "03" values the COL_X should have ""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can find out `A` and `B` cols using `grep`, then use `max.col` to find out row indices of values in `A_cols` having "03" as value then subset the corresponding value from `B_cols`.

```
A_cols <- grep("_A$", names(df))
B_cols <- grep("_B$", names(df))
df$COL_X <- df[B_cols][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df[A_cols] == "03"))]

df

#  ID DATA COL01_A  COL01_B COL02_A  COL02_B COL03_A  COL03_B    COL_X
#1  1  xxx      01 19990101      03 20000101      FF          20000101
#2  2  yyy      03 20170810      FA 20120303                  20170810
#3  3  zzz      GG 19940508      DD 20000101      03 20060808 20060808
#4  4  xyz      03 20180101      09 20000101                  20180101
#5  5  zxy      GF 20171212      03 19990101      02 20190101 19990101
```

As updated in the comment if there are more than 1 value of "03" in a particular row then we want an empty string as output. We can add an additional line for that condition after the above and it should work.

```
df$COL_X <- ifelse(rowSums(df[A_cols] == "03") > 1, "", df$COL_X)
```

Answer (score 0):

An idea is to use `split.default` and split the data frame based on its column names and then `coalesce`, i.e.

```
l1 <- lapply(split.default(df[-c(1, 2)], sub('_.*', '', names(df[-c(1, 2)]))), function(i)
                                               ifelse(i[[1]] == '03', i[[2]][i[[1]] == '03'], NA)) 

Reduce(dplyr::coalesce, l1)

#[1] "20000101" "20180101" "20060808" "20180101" "20000101"
```

If you don't want to call another library just for one function you can follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19254510/5635580) to get,

```
Reduce(function(x, y) {
     i <- which(is.na(x))
     x[i] <- y[i]
     x
 }, l1)
#[1] "20000101" "20180101" "20060808" "20180101" "20000101"
```

Stealing @RonakShah's handle for multiple `03` values,

```
A_cols <- grep("_A$", names(df))
df$COL_X <- ifelse(rowSums(df[A_cols] == "03") > 1, "", df$COL_X)
```