# String comparison in R not returning correct results for data

Tags: r, string, comparison

Some time ago i asked a question here ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54530570/how-to-keep-column-b-in-row-x-if-column-a-in-row-x-has-value) question) and it was correctly answered. Basically i needed to get the value from one specific column into a new column, depending on a sister column.

I tried using the same logic to get different values in a new case with the data. the problem now seems to be that either R or the function are failing to recognize proper values in the dataframe when doing the comparison.

The function in question is as follows:

```
    Obtain_SD <- function(df,dfx,atr,country){

      df <- dplyr::left_join(df,dfx,by=c("cd85"="cd")) //dfx has the DAR and DAT columns

      DAR_cols <- grep("DAR",colnames(df))
      DAT_cols <- grep("DAT",colnames(df))

      df$ex90 <- df[DAT_cols][cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(df[DAR_cols] == "90"))]
      return(df)
    }
```

According to this line:

```
df$ex90 <- df[DAT_cols][cbind(1:nrow(df),max.col(df[DAR_cols] == "90"))]
```

The program should add a column when it finds a value "90" in the `DAR_cols` with the value of the corresponding `DAT_cols`. This works fine in most of the cases but then this happens:

```
Browse[2]> df[422,"ex90"]
[1] NA
```

If i run some check commands i get the following answers:

```
Browse[2]> typeof(df[422,"DAR04"])
[1] "character"
Browse[2]> df[422,"DAR04"]
[1] "90"
Browse[2]> df[422,"DAR04"] == "90"
[1] TRUE
```

The column DAR04 (according to the summary(df) command) is of class `character` and mode `character` but the code returns for this line and some others (I change the format of the command for readability):

```
   ID CD    DATA DAR01 DAT01    ... DAR04 DAT04    ... DAR12 DAT12 ex90
   7  99034 ...  1     19000101 ... 90    20140715 ... NA    ""    NA
```

At the beginning i thought that there could be trailing or leading spaces but that's not the case. I don't know what else to check to solve my problem. any insight would be awesome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit to include only the most relevant pieces of code. The question as is long which affects the amount of attention it receives.

Comment: @NelsonGon edited as requested for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting the `NA` via `max.col(df[DAR_cols] == "90")`, since you have some `NAs` in the `DAR_cols`. E.g. `DAR12` appears to be `NA` in the example you printed.

I am also not entirely sure, whether you would actually want to use `max.col(..., ties.method = "last")`. The default is `ties.method = "random"`.

You could replace `max.col(df[DAR_cols] == "90")` with a custom `apply` that handles `NAs`:

```
unname(apply(df[DAR_cols] == "90", 1, function(x) {
  res <- which(x)
  if (length(res) == 0) res <- NA
  if (length(res) > 1) res <- max(res) # or use min(res) if you rather want the first
  res
}))
```