# Replace column condition dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

```
ID <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
AT <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5)
US <- c(NA,NA,0.6,NA,NA)
FIGX <- c(1,NA,NA,2,3)
W1 <- c(NA,10,20,30,40)
test.Data <- data.frame(ID,AT,US,FIGX,W1) %>% as.data.table()
```

I have this kind of table.
I would like to replace the values of column US by values of FIGX if NA, and if FIGX is NA, then to replace by the W1 column values.

I have tried this
`test.Data %>% mutate_if(is.na(US),mutate_if(is.na(FIGX),W1))`
without success.
How should I do?

Comment: `mutate(US = coalesce(US, FIGX, W1))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement coalesce efficiently in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r)

Comment: @camille I'd say that's not a good dupe - that's about how to write a function that does `coalesce` (and pre-dates the `dplyr` implementation by many years). This question is about using a `coalesce`-like function in dplyr, and the root of the issue seems to be a confusion between `mutate_if` and `ifelse`.

Comment: @IRT, your attempt would work if you use `ifelse` inside mutate, `test.Data %>% mutate(ifelse(is.na(US), ifelse(is.na(FIGX), W1, FIGX), US))`, but `coalesce` is made for replacing `NA`s like this and is much cleaner. Use `mutate_if` if you want to perform the exact same operation on multiple columns that meet a condition - e.g., round all numeric columns, or log all numeric columns that are strictly positive, or add a week to all date columns.

Comment: @Gregor that's fair, although the dplyr function is included in at least one answer there. I don't think the `mutate_if` issue is key though, since it's not the right use of that function anyway

Comment: I think OP's misunderstanding of `mutate_if` is the core of the question. OP thinks `mutate_if` works like `ifelse`. Letting them know about `coalesce` solves the specific case of replacing `NA`s, but the `mutate_if` confusion should be addressed now so they don't have a question tomorrow about why `mutate_if(x > 0, sqrt(x), -sqrt(-x))` doesn't work for a signed square root.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `daa.table` as the input data is already a `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
test.Data[is.na(US), US := coalesce(FIGX, W1)][]
test.Data
#   ID  AT   US FIGX W1
#1:  A 0.1  1.0    1 NA
#2:  B 0.2 10.0   NA 10
#3:  C 0.3  0.6   NA 20
#4:  D 0.4  2.0    2 30
#5:  E 0.5  3.0    3 40
```

For multiple columns, we can use `set`

```
colsOfInterest <- c("US", "AT")
for(nm in colsOfInterest){
   i1 <- which(is.na(test.Data[[nm]]))
   set(test.Data, i = i1 ,
         j = nm, value = coalesce(test.Data[["FIGX"]][i1], test.Data[["W1"]][i1]))
  }
```

Comment: `coalesce(US, FIGX, W1)`, no `case_when` needed.

Comment: How to generalize if I need to do this not only for US but for all possible columns (in fact I have like 30 columns ). I have been looking for a loop way.

Comment: Hi, when I execute the lines , I got an error: Error i set(tmp,i=i1,j=nm,value = coalesce(tmp[["FIGX"]][i1],tmp[["W1"]][i1]): unused argument (tmp[["W1"]][i1]). Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce it