# Filling a vector with other vectors

Tags: r

What I'd like to do is create a vector and filling it with values from other vectors. Namely:
I have:

```
a <- c(NA, 1, NA, 2, NA)
b <- c(1, NA, 4, NA, 5)
```

I want to end with something like:

```
c <- c(1,1,4,2,5)
```

These values may change every time I run the code and the length of the two first vectors may change, but the third one is always the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r

Answer (score 0):

We can use `coalesce`

```
library(dplyr)
c1 <- coalesce(a, b)
```

---

Or in `base R` either `pmin/pmax` can be used as long as both corresponding elements are non-NA

```
pmin(a, b, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 1 1 4 2 5
```