# How to merge multiple columns of a dataframe into one in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am once again asking a R/dataframe-related question. Recently, I have started implementing the merge() function, but I need help with merging some of the identical columns after merging different similar data frames together.

```
    library(dplyr)  
    library(tidyr)  
    library(stringr)  
    DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C"), TagNo=c(10,20,20),Info=c("Metal","Plastic","Wood"))
    DF2 = data.frame(ID=c("A","D","E"), TagNo=c(10,30,100),Info=c("Wood","Metal","Wood"))
    DF3 = data.frame(ID=c("B","C","F"), TagNo=c(20,20,40),Info=c("Glass","Metal","Wood"))
    dfmerge <- merge(DF1,DF2,by="ID",all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
    dfmerge <- merge(dfmerge,DF3,by="ID",all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
```

The resulting merged dataframe looks like this:

| ID | TagNo | Info.x | TagNo.y | Info.y | TagNo | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | Metal | 10 | Wood | NA | NA |
| B | 20 | Plastic | NA | NA | 50 | Glass |
| C | 20 | Wood | NA | NA | 20 | Metal |
| D | NA | NA | 30 | Metal | NA | NA |
| E | NA | NA | 100 | Wood | NA | NA |
| F | NA | NA | NA | NA | 40 | Wood |

I essentially want to condense the TagNo columns into just one Tag column. To highlight something important. Each sample has at least 1 TagNo, and if it has more than 1, it will always be the same. I don't ever have to worry about them being different.

This is the result I need:

| ID | TagNo.x | Info.x | Info.y | Info |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | Metal | Wood | NA |
| B | 20 | Plastic | NA | Glass |
| C | 20 | Wood | NA | Metal |
| D | 30 | NA | Metal | NA |
| E | 100 | NA | Wood | NA |
| F | 40 | NA | NA | Wood |

Does anyone know how to approach this problem? I appreciate any help. [Column headers aren't a big issue as I can simply fix that after with colnames(dfmerge) <- ...

Comment: Try with `coalesce` `library(dplyr);dfmerge$TagNo <- with(dfmerge, coalesce(TagNo.x, TagNo.y))`

Comment: This link may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you looking for `dplyr` joining functions ?

```r
library(dplyr)  
DF1 = data.frame(ID=c("A","B","C"),TagNo=c(10,20,20),Info=c("Metal","Plastic","Wood"))
DF2 = data.frame(ID=c("A","D","E"), TagNo=c(10,30,100),Info=c("Wood","Metal","Wood"))
DF3 = data.frame(ID=c("B","C","F"), TagNo=c(20,20,40),Info=c("Glass","Metal","Wood"))

DF1%>%
full_join(DF2,by=c("ID","TagNo"))%>%
full_join(DF3,by=c("ID","TagNo"))          
#>   ID TagNo  Info.x Info.y  Info
#> 1  A    10   Metal   Wood  <NA>
#> 2  B    20 Plastic   <NA> Glass
#> 3  C    20    Wood   <NA> Metal
#> 4  D    30    <NA>  Metal  <NA>
#> 5  E   100    <NA>   Wood  <NA>
#> 6  F    40    <NA>   <NA>  Wood
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Perfect, precisely what I wanted especially since the data I am working with has so many more vars and columns!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
dfmerge <- merge(DF1,DF2,by=c("ID", "TagNo"),all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
dfmerge <- merge(dfmerge,DF3,by=c("ID", "TagNo"),all.x=TRUE, all.y=TRUE)
```