replace NA values with values from another column
how would I impute values and replace the NAs in marks2 with marks1? I am getting an error with this code
df = data.frame(id=c(25,40,30,30),
                name=c('Chris','Scott','Anna','Ramana'),
                gender=c('m','m','f','m'),
                marks1=c(99,30,50,40),
                marks2=c(80,NA,NA,NA))

df$marks2[is.na(df$marks2)] <- df$marks1

Warning message:
In df$marks2[is.na(df$marks2)] <- df$marks1 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length


You need to subset on both sides of the assignment, e.g. df$marks2[is.na(df$marks2)] <- df$marks1[is.na(df$marks2)]. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253820/how-to-implement-coalesce-efficiently-in-r for more approaches.

The warning happens because df$marks1 has a different length from df$marks2[is.na(df$marks2)]
Base R
index <- which(is.na(df$marks2))
df$marks2[index] <- df$marks1[index]

Tidyverse
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(marks2 = if_else(is.na(marks2),marks1,marks2))


You could also try:
library(tidyverse)
df %>% mutate(marks2 = coalesce(marks2, marks1))

Or
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(marks2 = replace_na(marks2, marks1))


It is due to the different lenght of df$marks1 and df$marks2.You should try this.
df <- data.frame(id=c(25,40,30,30),
             name=c('Chris','Scott','Anna','Ramana'),
             gender=c('m','m','f','m'),
             marks1=c(99,30,50,40),
             marks2=c(80,NA,NA,NA))

df$marks2[is.na(df$marks2)] <- df$marks1[is.na(df$marks2)]
df


You can subset on both sides using replace.
> df |> transform(marks2=replace(marks2, is.na(marks2), marks1[is.na(marks2)]))
  id   name gender marks1 marks2
1 25  Chris      m     99     80
2 40  Scott      m     30     30
3 30   Anna      f     50     50
4 30 Ramana      m     40     40

