# Select the row with the maximum value in each group

Tags: r, dataframe, r-faq

In a dataset with multiple observations for each subject. For each subject I want to select the row which have the maximum value of 'pt'. For example, with a following dataset:

```
ID    <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)

group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value, Event=Event)
#   Subject pt Event
# 1       1  2     1
# 2       1  3     1
# 3       1  5     2 # max 'pt' for Subject 1
# 4       2  2     1
# 5       2  5     2
# 6       2  8     1
# 7       2 17     2 # max 'pt' for Subject 2
# 8       3  3     2
# 9       3  5     2 # max 'pt' for Subject 3
```

Subject 1, 2, and 3 have the biggest pt value of 5, 17, and 5 respectively.

How could I first find the biggest pt value for each subject, and then, put this observation in another data frame? The resulting data frame should only have the biggest pt values for each subject.

Comment: This is very closely related but for minimum instead of maximum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070714/extract-row-corresponding-to-minimum-value-of-a-variable-by-group

Comment: Related: [Subset by group with data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16573995/subset-by-group-with-data-table)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

Here's a `data.table` solution:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
group <- as.data.table(group)
```

If you want to keep all the entries corresponding to max values of `pt` within each group:

```
group[group[, .I[pt == max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1]
#    Subject pt Event
# 1:       1  5     2
# 2:       2 17     2
# 3:       3  5     2
```

If you'd like just the first max value of `pt`:

```
group[group[, .I[which.max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1]
#    Subject pt Event
# 1:       1  5     2
# 2:       2 17     2
# 3:       3  5     2
```

In this case, it doesn't make a difference, as there aren't multiple maximum values within any group in your data.

Comment: seeing as data.table has had a LOT of changes since 2014, is this still the fastest/best solution to this question?

Comment: @Ben, in this case, fastest answer is still this, yes. `.SD` optimisation for these cases is still on the list. Have an eye on [#735](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/735).

Comment: Hi, What is $V1 here? #noob

Comment: Accessing the auto-named column. Run it without it to understand better.

Comment: it works well. can you explain what ```.I``` does in data.table?

Comment: @HappyCoding, have a look at `?\`.I\`` and see if the explanation and examples there help?

Comment: .I holds the row location of the max entry per group, which is put in a column named V1.  Essentially, `group[, .I[which.max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1` is a vector of positions, and therefore can be used to subset.

Comment: Why it isn't faster if I first use setkey?

Answer (score 117):

The most intuitive method is to use `group_by` and `top_n` function in `dplyr`

```
group %>% group_by(Subject) %>% top_n(1, pt)
```

The result you get is

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
Groups: Subject [3]

  Subject    pt Event
    (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
1       1     5     2
2       2    17     2
3       3     5     2
```

Comment: dplyr is also useful when you want to access the smallest and largest value in a group because the values are available as an array. So you can first sort by pt descending and then use pt[1] or first(pt) to get the highest value:  ```group %>% group_by(Subject) %>% arrange(desc(pt), .by_group = TRUE) %>% summarise(max_pt=first(pt), min_pt=last(pt), Event=first(Event))```

Comment: This will include multiple rows if there are ties. Use `slice(which.max(pt))` to only include one row per group.

Answer (score 59):

A shorter solution using `data.table`:

```
setDT(group)[, .SD[which.max(pt)], by=Subject]
#    Subject pt Event
# 1:       1  5     2
# 2:       2 17     2
# 3:       3  5     2
```

Comment: Note that, this can be slower than `group[group[, .I[which.max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1]` as proposed above by @Arun; see comparisons [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41838383/5193830)

Comment: I like this one because it's fast enough for my current context and easier to grok for me vs the `.I` version

Comment: setDT(group)[, .SD[  pt== max(pt) ] , by=Subject]

Comment: How do you exclude cases where you have two max values?

Comment: Sorry to necro, but for future users: `setDT(group)[, .SD[which.max(pt)][1], by=Subject]` will take the first entry when there are multiple.

Answer (score 31):

Another option is `slice`

```
library(dplyr)
group %>%
     group_by(Subject) %>%
     slice(which.max(pt))
#    Subject    pt Event
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1       1     5     2
#2       2    17     2
#3       3     5     2
```

---

Using `dplyr` 1.1.0

```
slice_max(group, pt, by = 'Subject')
```

Answer (score 24):

Since {dplyr} v1.0.0 (May 2020) there is the new `slice_*` syntax which supersedes `top_n()`.

See also https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/slice.html.

```
library(tidyverse)

ID    <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)

group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value, Event=Event)

group %>% 
  group_by(Subject) %>% 
  slice_max(pt)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   Subject [3]
#>   Subject    pt Event
#>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1       1     5     2
#> 2       2    17     2
#> 3       3     5     2
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Answer (score 19):

A `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)
group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value, Event=Event)

group %>%
    group_by(Subject) %>%
    summarize(max.pt = max(pt))
```

This yields the following data frame:

```
  Subject max.pt
1       1      5
2       2     17
3       3      5
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to keep the `Event` column in the subset in which case you could do: `df %>% group_by(Subject) %>% filter(pt == max(pt))` (includes ties if present)

Answer (score 12):

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(group,as.factor(group$Subject)), function(x) {return(x[which.max(x$pt),])}))
```

Using Base `R`

Answer (score 10):

One more base R solution:

```
merge(aggregate(pt ~ Subject, max, data = group), group)

  Subject pt Event
1       1  5     2
2       2 17     2
3       3  5     2
```

Answer (score 8):

I wasn't sure what you wanted to do about the Event column, but if you want to keep that as well, how about

```
isIDmax <- with(dd, ave(Value, ID, FUN=function(x) seq_along(x)==which.max(x)))==1
group[isIDmax, ]

#   ID Value Event
# 3  1     5     2
# 7  2    17     2
# 9  3     5     2
```

Here we use `ave` to look at the "Value" column for each "ID". Then we determine which value is the maximal and then turn that into a logical vector we can use to subset the original data.frame.

Comment: Thanks very much but I have another question here. Why use with function in this method since ave(Value, ID, FUN=function(x) seq_along(x)==which.max(x))==1 works extremely fine? I am a little bit confused.

Comment: I used `with` because it's a bit odd to have the data available both inside and outside the `group` data.frame. If you read the data in with `read.table` or something, you would need to use `with` because those column names would not be available outside the data.frame.

Answer (score 6):

Another base solution

```
group_sorted <- group[order(group$Subject, -group$pt),]
group_sorted[!duplicated(group_sorted$Subject),]

# Subject pt Event
#       1  5     2
#       2 17     2
#       3  5     2
```

Order the data frame by `pt` (descending) and then remove rows duplicated in `Subject`

Answer (score 4):

In *base* you can use `ave` to get `max` per group and compare this with `pt` and get a logical vector to subset the `data.frame`.

```
group[group$pt == ave(group$pt, group$Subject, FUN=max),]
#  Subject pt Event
#3       1  5     2
#7       2 17     2
#9       3  5     2
```

Or using in addition `with`.

```
group[with(group, pt == ave(pt, Subject, FUN=max)),]
```

Or compare it already in the function.

```
group[as.logical(ave(group$pt, group$Subject, FUN=function(x) x==max(x))),]
#group[ave(group$pt, group$Subject, FUN=function(x) x==max(x))==1,] #Variant
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another `data.table` solution, since `which.max` does not work on characters

```
library(data.table)
group <- data.table(Subject=ID, pt=Value, Event=Event)

group[, .SD[order(pt, decreasing = TRUE) == 1], by = Subject]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(group)[, head(.SD[order(-pt)], 1), by = .(Subject)]
```

Answer (score 1):

`by` is a version of `tapply` for data frames:

```
res <- by(group, group$Subject, FUN=function(df) df[which.max(df$pt),])
```

It returns an object of class `by` so we convert it to data frame:

```
do.call(rbind, b)
  Subject pt Event
1       1  5     2
2       2 17     2
3       3  5     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(group)
group[group[order(-pt), .I[1L], Subject]$V1]
```

Or another (less readable but slightly faster):

```
group[group[, rn := .I][order(Subject, -pt), {
    rn[c(1L, 1L + which(diff(Subject)>0L))]
}]]
```

timing code:

```
library(data.table)
nr <- 1e7L
ng <- nr/4L
set.seed(0L)
DT <- data.table(Subject=sample(ng, nr, TRUE), pt=1:nr)#rnorm(nr))
DT2 <- copy(DT)


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(times=3L,
    mtd0 = {a0 <- DT[DT[, .I[which.max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1]},
    mtd1 = {a1 <- DT[DT[order(-pt), .I[1L], Subject]$V1]},
    mtd2 = {a2 <- DT2[DT2[, rn := .I][
        order(Subject, -pt), rn[c(TRUE, diff(Subject)>0L)]
    ]]},
    mtd3 = {a3 <- unique(DT[order(Subject, -pt)], by="Subject")}
)
fsetequal(a0[order(Subject)], a1[order(Subject)])
#[1] TRUE
fsetequal(a0[order(Subject)], a2[, rn := NULL][order(Subject)])
#[1] TRUE
fsetequal(a0[order(Subject)], a3[order(Subject)])
#[1] TRUE
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
 expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mtd0 3.256322 3.335412 3.371439 3.414502 3.428998 3.443493     3
 mtd1 1.733162 1.748538 1.786033 1.763915 1.812468 1.861022     3
 mtd2 1.136307 1.159606 1.207009 1.182905 1.242359 1.301814     3
 mtd3 1.123064 1.166161 1.228058 1.209257 1.280554 1.351851     3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr 1.0.2 there are now two ways to do this, one is long hand and the other is using the verb across():

```
      # create data
      ID    <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
      Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
      Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)
      
      group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value, Event=Event)
```

Long hand the verb is max() but note the na.rm = TRUE which is useful for examples where there are NAs as in the closed question: [Merge rows in a dataframe where the rows are disjoint and contain NAs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268814/merge-rows-in-a-dataframe-where-the-rows-are-disjoint-and-contain-nas):

```
       group %>% 
        group_by(Subject) %>% 
        summarise(pt = max(pt, na.rm = TRUE),
                  Event = max(Event, na.rm = TRUE))
```

This is ok if there are only a few columns but if the table has many columns across() is useful. The examples for this verb are often with summarise(across(start_with... but in this example the columns don't start with the same characters. Either they could be changed or the positions listed:

```
    group %>% 
        group_by(Subject) %>% 
        summarise(across(1:ncol(group)-1, max, na.rm = TRUE, .names = "{.col}"))
```

Note for the verb across() 1 refers to the first column *after* the first actual column so using ncol(group) won't work as that is too many columns (makes it position 4 rather than 3).

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes fall back on a solution around the `order` function, as this then works for any type of column (ie. not just numeric).  Basically, order the table by whatever you want to max or min, and then take the first or last of each group.

I also find this to be fairly easily readable for `data.table` beginners.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(group)[order(pt)][, last(.SD), by = Subject]
```

Note that replacing `last` with `first` achieves the equivalent of the minimum value.

Answer (score 0):

With `dplyr 1.1.0`, you can use `slice_max` with `by` to perform inline grouped slicing:

```r
library(dplyr)
group %>% 
  slice_max(pt, n = 1, by = Subject)

#  Subject pt Event
#1       1  5     2
#2       2 17     2
#3       3  5     2
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want the biggest pt value for a subject, you could simply use:

```
   pt_max = as.data.frame(aggregate(pt~Subject, group, max))
```