# How to retrieve row value corresponding to max value of a column in a data frame in R

Tags: r

As title suggested , I have a query to access the row value (not the index and not the entire row) corresponding to max value of a column.

FOR EX: I have below data set(results):

```
Name         subject      marks
sam           maths        88
paul          science      79
tom           social       66
james         english      78
richard       maths        83
```

Need help for following:

1. How to write command to retrieve row value ("sam") corresponding to max col value of marks (88)?

I was able to get the max value of marks column using the below command:

```
max(results$marks, na.rm = TRUE)
```

However, when I assign it to a variable to see who topped the exam, I get only the header names no the value as sam.

```
top_scorer<- results$Name[which.max(results$marks, na.rm = TRUEr)]
```

2. How to write a command to find out which person comes second on the list in terms of marks?

Please help. I am beginner in R programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select the row with the maximum value in each group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there. You actually use the `which.max` in your example code. To get the person who has the second highest `marks` you can order it by `marks` and take the second entry. This should work for both. We use `which.max` for the maximum and the sorting for the second maximum:

```
df <- data.frame(Name=c("sam","paul","tom","james", "richard"), 
                 subject=c("maths", "science", "social", "english", "maths"),
                 marks=c(88,79, 66, 78, 83))


df$max_name <- df$Name[which.max(df$marks)]
df <- df[order(df$marks,decreasing=T),]
df$second_max_name <- df$Name[2]
```

Note that you could use the sorting to get the max as well if you want, the `order` function defaults to putting `NA`s last.