# How can I extract the "best" row from each sub-category in my data frame?

Tags: r, subset, lapply

In the example below, the indices returned by the `order` function are used to sort the entries in each group by a :

```
set.seed(123)

ex.df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(LETTERS[1:4],20,replace=TRUE),
  score1 = sample(1:10),
  score2 = sample(1:10)
)

sortedOrderings <- by(ex.df, ex.df$group, function(df) order(df$score1 + df$score2) )

bestIndices <- lapply(sortedOrderings, FUN= function(lst) lst[1] )
```

The trouble is that `order` sees the indices of the data frame subsetted by `by` rather than `ex.df` itself, so using it to extract the relevant rows from the `ex.df` isn't the brightest idea:

```
print(sortedOrderings)

ex.df$group: A
[1] 2 3 4 1
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
ex.df$group: B
[1] 5 3 2 4 1
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
ex.df$group: C
[1] 2 1 3 4
--------------------------------------------------------------- 
ex.df$group: D
[1] 3 7 4 6 1 2 5

> print(ex.df[bestIndices,])
    group score1 score2
2       D      7      9
5       D      4      1
2.1     D      7      9
3       B      6      6
```

Is there a way to pull out the "best" row from each group in `ex.df`, or at least have the indices reference `ex.df`?

Comment: you could use `ave` to do the *split- apply-combine* for you : `with(ex.df, ex.df[ (score1 + score2) == ave(score1 + score2, group, FUN=max), ])` (although I'd probably do the sum on a previous line - and maybe use rowSums)

Comment: Actually from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group ; you will probs find a few ways to do this : *data.table*: `library(data.table) ; dt = as.data.table(ex.df)
dt[dt[, .I[(score1 + score2) == max(score1 + score2)], by=group]$V1]` , *dplyr* : `library(dplyr) ; ex.df %>% group_by(group) %>% top_n(1, score1+score2)`. If these are giving the expected outcome, it may be worth marking this as a dup??

Comment: I agree that this can be marked as a dupe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` to perform a self join on the indices of the first row where total score is equal to the max score by group:

```
set.seed(123)

ex.df <- data.frame(
  group = sample(LETTERS[1:4],20,replace=TRUE),
  score1 = sample(1:10),
  score2 = sample(1:10)
)

library(data.table)
setDT(ex.df)

ex.df[ex.df[,.I[(score1 + score2) == max(score1 + score2)][1],by = .(group)]$V1][order(group)]
```

Returns

```
   group score1 score2
1:     A      8      3
2:     B      9     10
3:     C     10      8
4:     D      9     10
```

Comment: @user20650 beat me to the punch on this one, only difference is that the extra `[1]`  approximately mid-line is necessary to ensure that only one row per group is returned in the event of a tie.

Comment: This works a treat. Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr` package and the `rank` function. It looks like this:

```
ex.df %>%
  mutate(total_score = score1 + score2) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(rank = rank(total_score)) %>%
  filter(rank == max(rank)) %>%
  select(-c(rank)) %>%
  arrange(group)
```

and gives you this:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   group [4]
   group score1 score2 total_score
  <fctr>  <int>  <int>       <int>
1      A      8      3          11
2      B      9     10          19
3      C     10      8          18
4      D      9     10          19
```