# Trouble in calculating minima by group in R

Tags: r, data.table, grouping

Using the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group), I have successfully calculated minima and maxima by group many times. This time it doesn't work and I don't understand why. Here is a reproducible example.

```
example <- structure(
  list(ID = 1:10, 
       date = 
         c("2005-05-09", "2006-09-18", "1996-06-14", "1997-01-06", 
           "1997-03-13", "1997-05-06", "1990-01-04", "1990-01-11", 
           "1989-12-28", "1989-12-28"), 
       name = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b")), 
  .Names = c("ID", "date", "name"), 
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
  row.names = c(NA, -10L))

example[example[, .I[which.min(date)], by=c("name")]$V1]
```

I was expecting something like:

```
1996-06-14    a
1989-12-28    b
```

but instead I get an empty data table. Why?

Comment: `example[, min(date), by=name]`

Comment: Your `date` column is a string. You need to convert it a `IDate` class first, e.g., `example[, date := as.IDate(date)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below let:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(example)
```

**1)** If you replace `date` with `xtfrm(date)` in your code it will work.

```
DT[DT[, .I[which.min(xtfrm(date))], by=c("name")]$V1]
```

giving:

```
   ID       date name
1:  3 1996-06-14    a
2:  9 1989-12-28    b
```

**2)** This gives just one minimum for each group:

```
DT[, .SD[which.min(xtfrm(date))], by = name]
```

giving:

```
   name ID       date
1:    a  3 1996-06-14
2:    b  9 1989-12-28
```

**3)** This gives all the minima for each group:

```
DT[, .SD[date == min(date)], by = name]
```

giving:

```
   name ID       date
1:    a  3 1996-06-14
2:    b  9 1989-12-28
3:    b 10 1989-12-28
```

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you! What's the meaning of .SD? I have never seen it before.

Comment: When by= is used it refers to the current subset of rows otherwise all rows.