# Find difference between maximum value of group and current row with R

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

Similar to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group), I am trying to find the difference between the maximum value of a group and the value of the current row.

For instance, if I have the following dataset:

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value)
```

How would I go about creating a new column called "diff" that would be the difference between the value of the current row and the maximum value in that group?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `group %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(diff=max(Value)-Value)`? Did you try anything? If so, please advise so we can see what didn't work for you.

Comment: I was trying with the data.table approach that I linked, but didn't have any success.

Comment: Ok ... it often helps (and is more relevant/absorbable by you) if we see your code and make corrections to your attempts. We can't correct a small mistake in code if you don't include the code and the error or incorrect output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP has tried a `data.table` solution. Here, we benefit from grouping and updating by reference simultaneously.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(group)[, diff := max(pt) - pt, by = Subject][]
```

> ```
>    Subject pt diff
> 1:       1  2    3
> 2:       1  3    2
> 3:       1  5    0
> 4:       2  2   15
> 5:       2  5   12
> 6:       2  8    9
> 7:       2 17    0
> 8:       3  3    2
> 9:       3  5    0
> ```

#### Data

```
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value)
```

#### Benchmark

At the time of writing, 5 answers were posted, including [Frank's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568656/find-difference-between-maximum-value-of-group-and-current-row-with-r?noredirect=1#comment90112011_51569126) on the efficiency of th `data.table` approach. So, I was wondering which of the five solutions were the fastest.

1. [r2evans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51568656/find-difference-between-maximum-value-of-group-and-current-row-with-r?noredirect=1#comment90103487_51568656)
2. mine
3. [Frank](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414#issuecomment-220135379)
4. [harelhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51569102/3817004)
5. [JonMinton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51571464/3817004)

Some solutions modify the data.frame in place. To ensure a fair comparison, In addition,

The OP has required to create a new column called "diff". For comparison, all results should return `group` with three columns. Some answers were modified accordingly. The answer of [harelhan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51569102/3817004) required substantial modifications to remove the errors.

As `group` is modified, all benchmark runs start with a fresh copy of `group` with two columns.

The benchmark is parameterized over the number of rows and the share of groups, i.e., the number of groups varies with the problem size in order to scale.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(bench)
bm <- press(
  # n_row = c(1E2, 1E4, 1E5, 1E6),
  n_row = c(1E2, 1E4, 1E5),
  grp_share = c(0.01, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9),
  {
    n_grp <- grp_share * n_row
    set.seed(1)
    group0 <- data.frame(
      Subject = sample(n_grp, n_row, TRUE),
      pt = as.numeric(rpois(n_row, 100)))
    mark(
      r2Evans = {
        group <- copy(group0)
        group <- group %>% 
          group_by(Subject) %>% 
          mutate(diff = max(pt) - pt)
        group
      },
      Uwe = {
        group <- copy(group0)
        setDT(group)[, diff := max(pt) - pt, by = Subject]
        group
      },
      Frank = {
        group <- copy(group0)
        setDT(group)[, mx := max(pt), by=Subject][, diff := mx - pt][, mx := NULL]
        group
      },
      harelhan = {
        group <- copy(group0)
        max_group <- group %>% group_by(Subject) %>% summarize(max_val = max(pt))
        group <- left_join(group, max_group[, c("Subject", "max_val")], by = "Subject")
        group$diff <- group$max_val - group$pt
        group <- group %>% select(-max_val)
        group
      },
      JonMinton = {
        group <- copy(group0)
        group <- group %>% 
          group_by(Subject) %>% 
          mutate(max_group_val = max(pt)) %>% 
          ungroup() %>% 
          mutate(diff = max_group_val - pt) %>% 
          select(-max_group_val)
        group
      }
    )
  }
)
ggplot2::autoplot(bm)
```

[image]

Comment: For efficiency, could do this in two stages and take advantage of gmax after https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1414 is done.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data and breaking the logic into smaller steps:

```
library(dplyr)
ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value)
max_group <- group %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarize(max_val = max(Value))
group <- left_join(group, max_group[,c(ID, max_val)], by = ID)
group$diff <- group$max_val - group$Value
```

Hope this solves the problem.

Comment: When I ran your code it says. *Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `ID` is unknown*. Furthermore, please show the result in order to verify and compare. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on harelhan's answer, but with piping:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data_frame(
  id = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  value = c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
)
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(max_group_val = max(value)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(diff_frm_group_max = max_group_val - value)

 A tibble: 9 x 4
      id value max_group_val diff_frm_group_max
   <dbl> <dbl>         <dbl>              <dbl>
 1     1     2             5                  3
 2     1     3             5                  2
 3     1     5             5                  0
 4     2     2            17                 15
 5     2     5            17                 12
 6     2     8            17                  9
 7     2    17            17                  0
 8     3     3             5                  2
 9     3     5             5                  0
```