# Why filter function is taking so much time to provide the output [example below] and is there any better way for filter?

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I am trying to execute a simple query as given below on data set with 20 million rows with 10 columns , but it is taking very long time to compute the final output (30 minutes) . Is there any better way to achieve the purpose ?

```
(t<-Sys.time())

rd_1<-as.data.frame(rd_1 %>%
group_by(customer,location_name,Location_Date,Location_Hour) %>%
filter(created_time==max(created_time))%>%
ungroup())

(t<-Sys.time())
```

Below is the timestamps after running the script ..

```
[1] "2018-12-19 09:15:47 GMT"

> rd_1<-as.data.frame(rd_1 %>%
+ group_by(customer,location_name,Location_Date,Location_Hour) %>%
+ filter(created_time==max(created_time))%>%
+ ungroup())

> (t<-Sys.time())

[1] "2018-12-19 09:45:25 GMT"
```

Comment: Try `data.table` option then https://stackoverflow.com/a/24558696/3962914

Comment: The grouping might take more time than the filter, try `. <- group_by(rd_1, customer,location_name,Location_Date,Location_Hour)` and `. <- filter(.,created_time==max(created_time))` and see which step takes time. Also what is `select(rd_1, customer, location_name, Location_Date, Location_Hour) %>% n_distinct` ?

Comment: I need to keep all columns after applying filter ...so I wont use select ... etc.... rd_1 is my data frame not a column so it wont be part of group by condition

Comment: why have you wrapped it all in `as.data.frame`?  that would make it spend a lot of time.

do you have the same issue with:

rd_1 %>%
 group_by(customer,location_name,Location_Date,Location_Hour) %>%
 filter(created_time==max(created_time))%>%
 ungroup() %>% as.data.frame()

Comment: It is still taking similar amount of time when i remove "as.data.frame" and use rd_1%>% ......

Comment: I would compute `max(created_time)` in a separate temp table and then make an `inner_join`. Also, I would measure the running time for each step individually.

Comment: How ? I am calculating max subject to certain conditions(group by) ....So how would u do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
temp <- rd_1 %>% 
  group_by(customer,location_name,Location_Date,Location_Hour) %>%
  summarise(created_time = max(created_time)) %>%
  ungroup()

rd_1 <- rd_1 %>% 
   inner_join(temp) %>% 
   as.data.frame()

rm(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , it worked for me ...Took 2 minutes instead of 30 minutes that my script was taking to finish the task..