# Filtering based on values in column

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57385460/in-r-how-can-i-filter-based-on-the-maximum-value-in-each-row-of-my-data) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group) but I just can't seem to work out how to adapt it to my situation. I have a 1437:60 dataframe with all numeric values. The first column is Depth and based on other data investigations I need to remove Depths (rows) that I have considered outliers.

For example:

```
Test <- data.frame(Depth = seq(from = 0, to = 100, by = 0.5), X1 = runif(n = 201, min = 1, max = 10), X2 - runif(n = 201, min = 1, max = 10))
```

I would like to remove the rows where Depth is between 46.5 and 48.5 AND rows where Depth is between 65.5 and 68.5. I have tried creating a vector and filtering based on that, e.g.

```
OutDepth <- c(seq(from = 46.5, to = 48.5, by = 0.5), seq(from = 65.5, to =  68.5, by = 0.5)

Test1 <- Test %>% filter(Depth == !OutDepths)
```

which gives an error of

```
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I get the same error if I try

```
Test1 <- Test[Test$Depths == !OutDepths, ]
```

Thanks in advance for any advice

**SOLUTION**
It turns out I simply had the location of the not (!) operator in the wrong spot and I should have been using `%in%` instead of `==`.

Eg.

```
Test1 <- Test %>%
filter(!Depth %in% OutDepths)
```

or base r

```
Test1 <- Test[!Test$Depth %in% OutDepths, ]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is another alternative from `between` function.

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(depth = c(20,40,47,50,60,67,80,90,100,120))

df %>% 
    filter(!between(depth, 46.5, 48.5)) %>% 
    filter(!between(depth, 65.5, 68.5))



#   depth
#1    20
#2    40
#3    50
#4    60
#5    80
#6    90
#7   100
#8   120
```

Comment: Thanks. This answer works and is slightly less code than @Gorka's solution. However, I am moving into dataframes with >100k rows and so I was looking for a more automated solution if possible. But this is definitely a reasonable start!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Test %>% 
  filter(Depth < 46.5 | Depth > 48.5) %>%
  filter(Depth < 65.5 | Depth > 68.5)
```

Comment: You can do it in one go: `filter(Depth < 46.5 | Depth > 48.5 & Depth < 65.5 | Depth > 68.5)`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Splitting it in two, IMHO is more readable.