# flag row with the maximum number in each row

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24558328/how-to-select-the-row-with-the-maximum-value-in-each-group), I was wondering how can you flag the row with the max number by group, while keeping all the other rows as well, instead of removing them?

Lets say i want to look for the max in `Value` for every `ID` separately. Then flag the max row with an `1` and all the others with `0`.

so, basically getting from this:

```
ID    <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)
DF <- data.table(cbind(ID, Value, Event))
DF
   ID Value Event
1:  1     2     1
2:  1     3     1
3:  1     5     2
4:  2     2     1
5:  2     5     2
6:  2     8     1
7:  2    17     2
8:  3     3     2
9:  3     5     2
```

to this:

```
DF
   ID Value Event flagMAX
1:  1     2     1       0
2:  1     3     1       0
3:  1     5     2       1
4:  2     2     1       0
5:  2     5     2       0
6:  2     8     1       1
7:  2    17     2       1
8:  3     3     2       0
9:  3     5     2       0
```

how can this be done? ideally with `data.table`

i tried :

```
DF[,flagMAX := ifelse(max(Value), 1, 0), by = "ID"]
```

but get all `1`

any ideas?

Comment: I think the 6th value should be 0 as  Value is max for 17 and not 8

Comment: ifelse() takes a logical vector... check ?ifelse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `data.table`, we can group by 'ID', coerce the logical vector to binary with (`as.integer` or `+`) and assign (`:=`) the output to create new column 'flagMAX'

```
library(data.table)
DF[, flagMAX := +(Value == max(Value)), ID]
```

If we are grouping by both 'ID' and 'Event'

```
DF[, flagMAX := +(Value == max(Value)), by = .(ID, Event)]
```

---

In the OP's code, the `ifelse` 'test' argument is not a logical vector, but a single numeric value from `max(Value)`, this gets coerced to logical resulting in any value greater than 0 to TRUE and others FALSE. Thus, resulting in 1 throughout

Illustration below

```
DF[, max(Value), ID]
#   ID V1
#1:  1  5
#2:  2 17
#3:  3  5
```

Now, we coerce it to logical

```
DF[, as.logical(max(Value)), ID]
#   ID   V1
#1:  1 TRUE
#2:  2 TRUE
#3:  3 TRUE
```

When we do the assignment with `ifelse(TRUE, 1, 0)`, it returns all 1s..  If we have a 0 value as max, it returns FALSE

```
as.logical(c(5, 17, 5, 0))
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you accept an answer with `tidyverse`

```r
library(tidyverse)

ID    <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)
DF <- data.frame(cbind(ID, Value, Event))

DF %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(flag = ifelse(Value == max(Value), 1,0))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>      ID Value Event  flag
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     1     2     1     0
#> 2     1     3     1     0
#> 3     1     5     2     1
#> 4     2     2     1     0
#> 5     2     5     2     0
#> 6     2     8     1     0
#> 7     2    17     2     1
#> 8     3     3     2     0
#> 9     3     5     2     1
```