# Turn dataframe two rows into one

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe where some rows are follow-ups of other other rows (completing each other) which I would like to combine into one row. Take the following example

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| rowID | name        | address   | age | firstId |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| 1     | Bert        |           | 60  |         |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| 2     | Ernie       | Berlin    | 72  |         |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| 3     | Bert Sesame | Amsterdam |     | 1       |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
```

The 3rd rowId refers back to the 1st RowId which in turn would make Bert 60 years old. Meanwhile the second row has no firstId (a row to follow-up on) and should be left as is.

Some columns can be filled in on both rows and I would like to take the row which has the firstID field filled in (thus the latest row). For example the 3rd row would have the name "Bert Sesame", i would like to use the name "bert sesame"  in that case, the row with a firstId value.

The end dataframe would be

```
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| rowID | name        | address   | age | firstId |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| 2     | Ernie       | Berlin    | 72  |         |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
| 3     | Bert Sesame | Amsterdam | 60  | 1       |
+-------+-------------+-----------+-----+---------+
```

How do I achieve this?

I have looked at questions such as this. [Merge two rows in data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45298997/merge-two-rows-in-data-frame)

But this refers to all rows by grouping them together. I only want to merge / combine rows which specifically refer to other rows.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, expected output and your attempt that failed

Comment: @Sotos I believe I added as you requested

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: I think you are looking for "fuzzy  matching", what happens if you have "Berty" instead of "Bert", would you merge it with "Bert Sesame"?

Comment: @zx8754 no I only want to merge rows which the column firstId specifically refers to. The records always exist and have a ID to refer to.

Comment: Oh, I see, missed that column, yes you are right. Then look into merge, and fill NA and remove duplicated rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt using `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
 group_by(rowID_new = replace(rowID, firstId != '', firstId[firstId != ''])) %>% 
 mutate(age = replace(age, age == '', age[age != ''])) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 filter(!rowID %in% firstId) %>% 
 select(-rowID_new)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 5
>   rowID name  address age   firstId
>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
> 1     2 B     E       72    ""     
> 2     3 C     F       60    1
> ```

**EDIT:**
If you have multiple variables to fill, we can replace `''` with `NA` and use `fill`, i.e.

```
df %>% 
 mutate_all(function(i) replace(i, i == '', NA)) %>% 
 group_by(rowID_new = replace(rowID, !is.na(firstId), firstId[!is.na(firstId)])) %>% 
 fill(-rowID, .direction = 'up') %>% #you might not need this[with .direction = 'up']
 fill(-rowID) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 filter(!rowID %in% firstId)
```

which gives,

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 6
>   rowID name  address age   firstId rowID_new
>   <dbl> <chr> <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>    
> 1     3 C     F       60    1       1        
> 2     2 B     E       72    <NA>    2
> ```

**EXAMPLE USED**

```
structure(list(rowID = c(1, 2, 3), name = c("A", "B", "C"), address = c("D", 
"E", "F"), age = c("60", "72", ""), firstId = c("", "", "1")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Yes this works but this will only work for the one column "age", ive got 200 columns in total which need to be merged just like age here

Comment: @KrijnvanderBurg edited. Please let me know If that's ok

Comment: Took me quite a lot of testing to verify it worked ok. its working perfectly! thank you very much