# How to merge 2 columns within the same dataframe in R

Tags: r

I am trying to merge 2 columns within the same dataset in order to condense the number of columns.

The dataset currently looks like this:

I am trying to merge 2 columns within the same dataset in order to condense the number of columns.

The dataset currently looks like this:

```
Year Var1 Var2 
2014 123   123 
2014 NA    155 
2015 541   NA 
2015 432   432 
2016 NA    124
```

I wish the dataset to look like

```
    Year Var1.2 
    2014 123    
    2014 155
    2015 541   
    2015 432   
    2016 124
```

I tried this code:

```
df$Var1.2 <- paste(df$Var1,df$Var2)
```

But I can this:

```
    Year Var1.2 
    2014 123 123 
    2014 NA 155 
    2015 541 NA 
    2015 432 432 
    2016 NA 124
```

Somewhere had a suggestion?

Comment: What happens if there are 2 non-NA values in a row? So, if 2017 had the values 214 and 567, what would you want `Var1.2` to be for that row?

Comment: In my case, it's impossible, I will have the same number, a number and NA, or NA and NA - divibisan.

Comment: zack, I didn't understand the example..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/dplyr/versions/0.7.3/topics/coalesce)

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Var1.2 = coalesce(Var1, Var2)) 

#>   Year Var1 Var2 Var1.2
#> 1 2014  123  123    123
#> 2 2014   NA  155    155
#> 3 2015  541   NA    541
#> 4 2015  432  432    432
#> 5 2016   NA  124    124
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1.9000)</sup>

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/14268814/786542

Comment: Sorry, I observed a mistake in my final dataset. I obtained the following result:
`#>   Year Var1 Var2 Var1.2
#> 1 2014  123  123    123
#> 2 2014   NA  155    NA
#> 3 2015  541   NA    541
#> 4 2015  432  432    432
#> 5 2016   NA  124    NA` 
this command replace only the values of right column.

Comment: This message appears:
`Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(NA, NA, 64L, NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated`

Comment: The problem was resolved. I solved this problem using this: 
`df$Var1=as.character.default(df$Var1)` and
`df$Var2=as.character.default(df$Var2)`.