# data.frame manipulation by column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame that I want to manipulate in a way that the two rows containing USD (and EUR) in CP variable get joined:

| Datum | CP | mnozstvi | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-30 | USD | 10 | NA |
| 2021-07-30 | EUR | 5 | NA |
| 2021-07-30 | X | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | X | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | X | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | USD | NA | 10 |
| 2021-07-30 | EUR | NA | 5 |

Desired data.frame:

| Datum | CP | mnozstvi | close |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-30 | USD | 10 | 10 |
| 2021-07-30 | EUR | 5 | 5 |
| 2021-07-30 | X | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | X | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-07-30 | X | 1 | 1 |

I dont know how to do it. Ideally using dplyr. this is just minimal case, mine is mooore complicated.

Comment: Try `coalesce()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642210/how-to-merge-2-columns-within-the-same-dataframe-in-r/55642536#55642536 & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268814/merge-rows-in-a-dataframe-where-the-rows-are-disjoint-and-contain-nas/52524260#52524260

Comment: Does not work in this case... I want to basically combine two rows containing USD ( and EUR) in CP variable

Comment: If things are always even like this (same # NA in each group), maybe remove NA with something like `dat %>% group_by(Datum, CP) %>% summarise(across(mnozstvi:close, na.omit))`.