# Group By Multiple Columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr, data-manipulation

I have a data set that I am looking at ... 3 columns that have `name`, `store`, and `amount` .... looks like this

```
name        store     amount
John Doe    Target    150
```

Now the trick is this `John Doe` may be in the file again but with this data

```
name        store     amount
John Doe    Walmart   50
```

I want to summarize and *ADD* new columns for all of John Doe's activity like the following:

```
name        store A   amount A   store B   amount B
John Doe    Target    150        Walmart   50
```

- I have tried `transpose` and `ddlyr` but am not having any luck.
- I have tried transpose and group by but it seems like you can't group by multiple columns

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! Please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to make a good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In particular, the easiest way to get a quick answer is to provide sample data (that can be copy pasted), example of desired output, and the code you have already tried that doesn't give your desired output. It is definitely possible to group by multiple columns but without knowing exactly what you have tried we can't see the misunderstanding clearly.

Comment: Base R's `by` accepts as its second argument a list of columns, so something like `by(x, x[,c("name","store"), function(z) { ... })` will get you each person in each store, individually (you need to fill in the `...` here). If you're into `tidyverse` packages, then `group_by(x, name, store)` works well, too. And `data.table` provides `xDT[, ..., by=c("name", "store")]`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to reshape data from long to wide format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution that works for the particular example you've given, but I don't find it particularly elegant and it wouldn't work if you have more than 2 occurrences for each name (in that case you'd have to give more options to the `mutate` verb.

```
df <- tibble(name = c("John Doe"),
             store = c("Target", "Walmart"),
             amount = c(150, 50))

coalesce_by_column <- function(df) {
    return(dplyr::coalesce(!!! as.list(df)))
}

df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    mutate(store_k = c("store A", "store B"),
           amount_k = c("amount A", "amount B")) %>% 
    spread(store_k, store) %>%
    spread(amount_k, amount) %>%
    summarise_all(coalesce_by_column)
```

The `coalesce_by_column` function combines the disjointed rows that contain NAs (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14268814/merge-rows-in-a-dataframe-where-the-rows-are-disjoint-and-contain-nas/33282598#33282598) for more details). If you want to rearrange the column order, you can easily do it with `select`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I got something with the Mutate function ....the mutate function is pretty awesome and I think I got a solution now !

Comment: Great! Maybe you could update your question with the solution that worked for you in the end.